# Formatting using a variable number of .format( ) arguments in Python

Tags: python, templates, variables, format

I can't seem to figure out a straightforward way to make code that finds the number of items to format, asks the user for the arguments, and formats them into the original form.

A basic example of what I'm trying to do is as follows (user input starts after ">>> "):

```
>>> test.py
What is the form? >>> "{0} Zero {1} One"
What is the value for parameter 0? >>> "Hello"
What is the value for parameter 1? >>> "Goodbye"
```

The program would then use print(form.format()) to display the formatted inputs:

```
Hello Zero Goodbye One
```

However if the form had 3 arguments, it would ask for parameters 0, 1 and 2:

```
>>> test.py (same file)
What is the form? >>> "{0} Zero {1} One {2} Two"
What is the value for parameter 0? >>> "Hello"
What is the value for parameter 1? >>> "Goodbye"
What is the value for parameter 2? >>> "Hello_Again"
Hello Zero Goodbye One Hello_Again Two
```

This is the most basic application that I can think of that would use a variable amount of things to format. I have figured out how to make variables as I need them using vars() but as string.format() can't take in lists, tuples, or strings, I can't seem to make ".format()" adjust to the number of things there are to format.

Comment: `myargs = ['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Hello_Again']; myString.format(*myargs)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fmt=raw_input("what is the form? >>>")
nargs=fmt.count('{') #Very simple counting to figure out how many parameters to ask about
args=[]
for i in xrange(nargs):
    args.append(raw_input("What is the value for parameter {0} >>>".format(i)))

fmt.format(*args)
          #^ unpacking operator (sometimes called star operator or splat operator)
```

Comment: Not only did you give a great solution, but using format on the input makes the program way simpler than the way I had it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply try to format using whatever data you have, and if you get an `IndexError` you don't have enough items yet, so ask for another one. Keep the items in a list and unpack it using the `*` notation when calling the `format()` method.

```
format = raw_input("What is the format? >>> ")
prompt = "What is the value for parameter {0}? >>> "
parms  = []
result = ""
if format:
    while not result:
        try:
            result = format.format(*parms)
        except IndexError:
             parms.append(raw_input(prompt.format(len(parms))))
print result
```

Comment: Just to be complete, you should probably check that `format` isn't `''`

Comment: Yeah, that's where I would put it too.  Good answer now.  I like it slightly better than mine (+1) -- *edit* why did you move it?  `while format and not result` seems cleaner to me.  Performance isn't an issue here since you're waiting for user input anyway...

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it was clearer as a separate statement. Tomato, tomato.

Comment: Funny, when I read that, `Tomato` and `tomato` sound the same in my head ;).

Comment: you don't need to check `if format` if you use `while True:` instead of `while not result` (add `break` if there is no exception)

Comment: it won't work if `format="{0}"` and user inputs empty string (the result should be empty in this case). See the fix in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11435979/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified kindall's answer that allows empty result for non-empty format string:

```
format = raw_input("What is the format? >>> ")
prompt = "What is the value for parameter {0}? >>> "
params  = []

while True:
    try:
        result = format.format(*params)
    except IndexError:
        params.append(raw_input(prompt.format(len(params))))
    else:
        break
print result
```

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the best solution. I hate manually breaking out of loops if it can be avoided (far more elegant to write a proper condition) but it doesn't seem possible in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use * in front of the last parameter name and all subsequent ones will be grouped into that one. You can then iterate over that list as you desire.

[How to make variable argument lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python)