# Using a data structure to pass multiple arguments

Tags: python

Is it possible to use a single data structure to pass into a function with multiple arguments? I'd like to do something like the following but it doesn't appear to work.

```
foo_bar = (123, 546)

def a(foo, bar):
    print(foo)
    print(bar)
```

Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
a(foo_bar)
```

instead of:

```
a(foo_bar[0], foo_bar[1])
```

What is the pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you want is:

```
a(*foo_bar)
```

See [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the tutorial for details… but there really isn't much more to it than this.

For completeness, the reference documentation is in [Calls](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, `expression` must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are positional arguments x1, ..., xN, and `expression` evaluates to a sequence y1, ..., yM, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional arguments x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python