# (Python 2.7) Use a list as an argument in a function?

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, arguments

So I'm trying to learn Python using codecademy but I'm stuck. It's asking me to define a function that takes a list as an argument. This is the code I have:

```
# Write your function below!    
def fizz_count(*x):
    count = 0
    for x in fizz_count:
        if x == "fizz":
            count += 1
    return count
```

It's probably something stupid I've done wrong, but it keeps telling me to make sure the function only takes one parameter, "x". `def fizz_count(x):` doesn't work either though. What am I supposed to do here?

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone, I see what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322068/python-passing-list-as-argument

Comment: @devnull That question is about mutation, this is about not unpacking `*args`.

Comment: @askewchan  Right.  Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a handful of problems here:

1. You're trying to iterate over `fizz_count`. But `fizz_count` is your function. `x` is your passed-in argument. So it should be `for x in x:` (but see #3).
2. You're accepting one argument with `*x`. The `*` causes `x` to be a tuple of *all* arguments. If you only pass one, a list, then the list is `x[0]` and items of the list are `x[0][0]`, `x[0][1]` and so on. Easier to just accept `x`.
3. You're using your argument, `x`, as the placeholder for items in your list when you iterate over it, which means after the loop, `x` no longer refers to the passed-in list, but to the last item of it.  This would actually work in this case because you don't use `x` afterward, but for clarity it's better to use a different variable name.
4. Some of your variable names could be more descriptive.

Putting these together we get something like this:

```
def fizz_count(sequence):
    count = 0
    for item in sequence:
        if item == "fizz":
           count += 1
    return count
```

I assume you're taking the long way 'round for learning porpoises, which don't swim so fast. A better way to write this might be:

```
def fizz_count(sequence):
    return sum(item == "fizz" for item in sequence)
```

But in fact `list` has a `count()` method, as does `tuple`, so if you know for sure that your argument is a list or tuple (and not some other kind of sequence), you can just do:

```
def fizz_count(sequence):
    return sequence.count("fizz")
```

In fact, that's so simple, you hardly need to write a function for it!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out such a helpful response. Yeah codecademy has a habit of making you do everything in the longest and most inefficient way possible, but at least I'm still learning!

Answer (score 1):

when you pass `*x` to a function, then `x` is a list. Do either

```
def function(x):
   # x is a variable
   ...
function('foo') # pass a single variable
funciton(['foo', 'bar']) # pass a list, explicitly
```

or

```
def function(*args):
   # args is a list of unspecified size
   ...
function('foo') # x is list of 1 element
function('foo', 'bar') # x is list with two elements
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't taking a list as an argument. `*x` expands to consume your passed arguments, so your function is expecting to be called like this:

```
f(1, 2, 3)
```

Not like this:

```
f([1, 2, 3])
```

Notice the lack of a list object in your first example. Get rid of the `*`, as you don't need it:

```
# Write your function below!    
def fizz_count(lst):
    count = 0

    for elem in lst:
        if elem == "fizz":
            count += 1

    return count
```

You can also just use `list.count`:

```
# Write your function below!    
def fizz_count(lst):
    return lst.count('fizz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Write your function below!    
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for i in x:
        if i == "fizz":
            count += 1
    return count
```

Sample :

```
>>> fizz_count(['test','fizz','buzz'])
1
```

`for i in x:` will iterate through every elements of list `x`. Suggest you to read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score 0):

It must be a typo. You're trying to iterate over the function name.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    counter = 0
    for element in x:
        if element == "fizz":
            counter += 1
    return counter
```