# zip iterators asserting for equal length in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am looking for a nice way to `zip` several iterables raising an exception if the lengths of the iterables are not equal.

In the case where the iterables are lists or have a `len` method this solution is clean and easy:

```
def zip_equal(it1, it2):
    if len(it1) != len(it2):
        raise ValueError("Lengths of iterables are different")
    return zip(it1, it2)
```

However, if `it1` and `it2` are generators, the previous function fails because the length is not defined `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`.

I imagine the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module offers a simple way to implement that, but so far I have not been able to find it. I have come up with this home-made solution:

```
def zip_equal(it1, it2):
    exhausted = False
    while True:
        try:
            el1 = next(it1)
            if exhausted: # in a previous iteration it2 was exhausted but it1 still has elements
                raise ValueError("it1 and it2 have different lengths")
        except StopIteration:
            exhausted = True
            # it2 must be exhausted too.
        try:
            el2 = next(it2)
            # here it2 is not exhausted.
            if exhausted:  # it1 was exhausted => raise
                raise ValueError("it1 and it2 have different lengths")
        except StopIteration:
            # here it2 is exhausted
            if not exhausted:
                # but it1 was not exhausted => raise
                raise ValueError("it1 and it2 have different lengths")
            exhausted = True
        if not exhausted:
            yield (el1, el2)
        else:
            return
```

The solution can be tested with the following code:

```
it1 = (x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c'])  # it1 has length 3
it2 = (x for x in [0, 1, 2, 3])     # it2 has length 4
list(zip_equal(it1, it2))           # len(it1) < len(it2) => raise
it1 = (x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c'])  # it1 has length 3
it2 = (x for x in [0, 1, 2, 3])     # it2 has length 4
list(zip_equal(it2, it1))           # len(it2) > len(it1) => raise
it1 = (x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])  # it1 has length 4
it2 = (x for x in [0, 1, 2, 3])          # it2 has length 4
list(zip_equal(it1, it2))                # like zip (or izip in python2)
```

Am I overlooking any alternative solution? Is there a simpler implementation of my `zip_equal` function?

**Update:**

- Requiring python 3.10 or newer, see Asocia's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773251/446149)
- Thorough performance benchmarking and best performing solution on python<3.10: Stefan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485272/446149)
- Simple answer without external dependencies:
  Martijn Pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32954700/446149) (please check the comments for a bugfix in some corner cases)
- More complex than Martijn's, but with better performance: cjerdonek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40596355/446149)
- If you don't mind a package dependency, see
  pylang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61832383/446149)

Comment: This question (and I guess its answers) was btw referenced by [PEP 618 -- Add Optional Length-Checking To zip](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0618/#do-nothing), which brought this to to Python 3.10. As evidence that *"hand-writing a robust solution that gets this right isn't trivial"* :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new solution even much faster than cjerdonek's on which it's based, and a benchmark. Benchmark first, my solution is green. Note that the "total size" is the same in all cases, two million values. The x-axis is the number of *iterables*. From 1 iterable with two million values, then 2 iterables with a million values each, all the way up to 100,000 iterables with 20 values each.

[image: benchmark plot]

The black one is Python's `zip`, I used Python 3.8 here so it doesn't do this question's task of checking for equal lengths, but I include it as reference/limit of the maximum speed one can hope for. You can see my solution is pretty close.

For the perhaps most common case of zipping *two* iterables, mine's almost three times as fast as the previousy fastest solution by cjerdonek, and not much slower than `zip`. Times as text:

```
         number of iterables     1     2     3     4     5    10   100  1000 10000 50000 100000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       more_itertools__pylang 209.3 132.1 105.8  93.7  87.4  74.4  54.3  51.9  53.9  66.9  84.5
   fillvalue__Martijn_Pieters 159.1 101.5  85.6  74.0  68.8  59.0  44.1  43.0  44.9  56.9  72.0
     chain_raising__cjerdonek  58.5  35.1  26.3  21.9  19.7  16.6  10.4  12.7  34.4 115.2 223.2
     ziptail__Stefan_Pochmann  10.3  12.4  10.4   9.2   8.7   7.8   6.7   6.8   9.4  22.6  37.8
                          zip  10.3   8.5   7.8   7.4   7.4   7.1   6.4   6.8   9.0  19.4  32.3
```

**My code** ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVNNb9swDL3nVxDYIXYhFFjaDYOxHttzD0UvRRFoDt0IUCSNottmw357RsmJv5qd5kNi6ZF85Ht02PPWu6tvgQ6HhvwODCOx9zaC2QVPDPVWG7dYbLCBXyas8WerbXGRwvQPi7GsFguQ5xPceQIm82q0hVpHjAraiBBawpR5mcNMAxZdMaTDd1hVGUoPIbfkUviY4sTwoI2FJtFsERpDkeEUlCPy1TqyDwE3cAN32sYOSd13KEuNohwYnXfW19LyNLnH5zUfqMVZu/1xb9BuzjYrA/V9JBXnXYgszvOUbEAzlTYi5qO2Ld4SeSqaZW9HNRMDTATr3QvSshwGkVbWYFxn6GUye31KKAgjl/9HGLeyLRPGD5Lct5zVCAZrjMD@BeVI3WKc3BaN0/toRQZvBcvdFw7feRShJuZ2CWkkibcmcrHTIUergaaPygvXVU1rlwspuMiKqJFZZfcNsNxP1z@VCWQci0K/x2P8OWrRgUup2FqO1fGWaV9NzCH/luz5x0c2FvVYUN6WKqUNkg8IoNvIwgbUNTattfsjLb7XGHjkK@gIWJ2tkOBKKHA8h@iQNXj6rGD1rODpSsF1@v@i4OtzOQfTz/VwnY4rBWev@2Ll4fAX)):

```
def zip_equal(*iterables):

    # For trivial cases, use pure zip.
    if len(iterables) < 2:
        return zip(*iterables)

    # Tail for the first iterable
    first_stopped = False
    def first_tail():
        nonlocal first_stopped 
        first_stopped = True
        return
        yield

    # Tail for the zip
    def zip_tail():
        if not first_stopped:
            raise ValueError('zip_equal: first iterable is longer')
        for _ in chain.from_iterable(rest):
            raise ValueError('zip_equal: first iterable is shorter')
            yield

    # Put the pieces together
    iterables = iter(iterables)
    first = chain(next(iterables), first_tail())
    rest = list(map(iter, iterables))
    return chain(zip(first, *rest), zip_tail())
```

The basic idea is to let `zip(*iterables)` do all the work, and then after it stopped because some iterable was exhausted, check whether all iterables were equally long. They were if and only if:

1. `zip` stopped because the *first* iterable didn't have another elements (i.e., no other iterable is *shorter*).
2. None of the other iterables have any further elements (i.e., no other iterable is *longer*).

How I check these criteria:

- Since I need to check these criteria after `zip` ended, I can't return the `zip` object purely. Instead, I chain an empty `zip_tail` iterator behind it that does the checking.
- To support checking the first criterion, I chain an empty `first_tail` iterator behind it whose sole job is to log that the first iterable's iteration stopped (i.e., it was asked for another element and it didn't have one, so the `first_tail` iterator was asked for one instead).
- To support checking the second criterion, I fetch iterators for all the other iterables and keep them in a list before I give them to `zip`.

Side note: more-itertools pretty much uses the same method as Martijn's, but does proper `is` checks instead of Martijn's [not quite correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954486/zip-iterators-asserting-for-equal-length-in-python#comment67540762_32954700) `sentinel in combo`. That's probably the main reason it's slower.

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVhtb@M2Ev6uXzG3QWEppzhOclscjHNwizY9BOhtg9307oDAUGiJjrWRKJWkE7uL/Pa9GVKi3pxuuogNxJH5MjOceeaZocqtXhXi7O@l/PIlzctCatBpzlPtVb9SzaUuikx5S1nkzU@o5iUvOdMhxCuWihB@T8soK8QdV9puiIss47FOC@G2JPy3NbezautGV3zzwKXChSHkbKPS37nnHRy95sc7gI9FtiZjYLGFfzOp008CrlKOp1KvrcxL@NL4A4/Lsihapln2wLI1j6JKc1Rp9g/JrWyRcRVMPcCP4kKngmcwg2LxCf3nB2Z8WUj0aL4oIBVtX7ckhOAUzWoxlVT6pMtGOMowwppZ@kiWKg7/IQEXUhbSH13WsmHFHjgk6XLJJQqBjIs7vVKjwAnYpjxLrNQ9R6/cZkzc7TtoeSF55EAfRVbrMGCS67UU0F/uJLV3eF6UM3nPZTu6RnGzPrrjAtdrdH9f1Z/EQKWrBQESgHPPhB8BYiYVVDu70w1CfhXGUgcOC5ZnoECne5FzrLY3b97c3uL87S3oFUdLy7WGZtUh6OKO44wMYYEzxiCz8fZ2p1koB8@FG7bAELkjDSzLjGjFcl7heOw528/Pz5HqohOMkMR4c/8s6M@d4hwZ5I/YIh51p7MUw9EcjySFZk/QrLvxJyGM2CgIwcfZ0cI8neITSpt/uynJy22BA0iKWCN2pvDXy3@9/@XDRXTxvx8urq4vf3kf/Xhx/e7yZyfrWrKYL1h8D35eKCL@mCggJkdmTOkWwMbjsXvuBn1MP8c7QzSF52jGyaroxqsh4lV4bUoHnM9gsjmbvJtM3n3fGPTIpEjFnRrTg9/Bsz9A98g5Cx4xi2DB8ax58cATyhgGyzWmOodaY7GE0VAGnfOoOTb8iglDcFus00zbvEVBwhRGVKNXu4QoLdNYz67lmlJAac6ScXdZEHZ@/shLDAsjof@1R27mLSoO4IcVxxg@rkz62Oxyfsfc6CYGVWEbSy23LQZJpdIRTSLyMCoNR91M5kGHaFICGzmOi3VOjMZbi0@m8xBOgi7DdMQGfW4ys3@ZtUwY8tNCcnbvRnmmemsO4HIJj4SwhKjALIdijV0MDsZMwLodrSMbrnG3SFq@x/Eus@9Q0ZZPPucIR3Q15KnKmY5XjeA/4tWEa5ZmauY3Bw/JufQQ1LFFnUxsoRCcYNmNbXVYk1qsSiXcrplp4liCYKmk4L4c1tgjZEaSXGPrhtZbO/km5qWG621pu4PGs5VLvlLD9twVxJ@4TNDq@1dvDGIkOQUXmxVbYyYmNioXxhuou8KwKeJRKpBfI1/xbIkxEgnftCCOvHVtShoOU5WlKE2OFkwZfqHBKnS8VuWCOK45z7aI2XJsN8zsRltlCUQYS8O5ftrU0w82PIhuIw6jglpYVTsVjXfP5pRZVPYOnlrImRpv9aLQPBWY35Xm0Jn97TYAzhlXiKQxx8pouNXcPBzCwr4DgkFPZzZE9bLIQWbYhtRWKnTxTe@Ah0zeqcBwHD09Q3FYyQfsaRsjc/9p@IO0BO0M63tC0USrj68ij4MWBe0O306ew2RXZ/@BUjuve/vaUvj81EKcIZnRGA@HFOVbCAfW5PfoqhbN2XJiokiVozBVpfGbrSiqaGSPh@WhgsLQgyTCFgnDU7N@qei4tf4IvtFue7d@7HTtUEKJmd7dNyghL3EnJrdpzWXjyJ1OpM9@WfGj5ktMrqsiXuVMiH1fmvCRilUUWb1RrbebYFW1@YlIQKYPKfZbMbIgXl6o/JbUY7myi5jutBkB/ANOB6VnZzU@gGu0xYCNqMQg21GT1@pmdFGWCP0Z/ISA5Y7O7Sydx2@hTxQiK7D37W3ud0hOJvVwPXO7fLDTWDyQs4P827cC3SIK3VX2lcv8smlvpz1ntADb7eEic1Uk1hwTeqN6gy95p@//FoVqVUjd0ThwydXaVoEyxSuHcle/hqFNf1NdgVrhd3HAOVskGmowK8JOcIOqvJj15taUs9KsbkqZcqsM4KxUgp0RFMKh8UjYCtY@Gp6f0TjqElSV4uQTuqaokvOErnM8efUUb3RhKTQ@@OpbkrC/7Pk3YIOlz9XowcLnuMYtDL25JSiBFxq/Pkb3tU09Oo4iWhVFNydYdQChT@Ad7SGE1AK6cEFcJHwvpEzS/TwE0fRgH51WqtdNWM0lNG8lFAIMC3LGc7yCY/PB8KZCPZiRg1sjqnqEhs@1jCnczA1f1ANEG07Bk2MyTPlH3K2RQFrkUcpUaGSLz/lTq38oltVVBT6Lafg0rXiCXlJxuSiwLHfE9XWghb75DqEX@UbloT/67iyBXMEIvgNtyZdMNxt7N2zowaihLa/DlvWrmu5bt52O6bU0lVcV0WLi25fxY/uW3c9YvkjY1L5Bd0bgCar5lCJt@6rGiDwIkJEm@IfN1YLL2UlYvbWfvQ2Cm@nZfKcBN7JYCzQADuGEn4VwFvQ8093mEHFTmzUfM6xHwp5BDS7y/fjtCpW3a72NWs/xrQW98I4WhHVsgrB5n7bKzAA2fyJILZNRqr/j7CHc8@0MJ4Ndx@lbxja1ZQOrXmDRi61hm4E1tTOtcs20qqOGtDHoeAFuvnreHZueP8R8L/URW3L7CstRnTGAI0KwY7NZYKjFkd3rl0tyJWXR3Ktw6RpLXWgsXI5YZ3BKKTY5PPzeIzNzchCm6CmmXAh/C@FtiLP0Z7@qb/z3dtL8qm56Nd/3dBwfQ74PR18Renquxg5onaFOOgs18qmNRZkVWmMtBxVLLNmv7vAqpRKmmVHt9GF@rbQu1fT4GFkvQzKNi/z4n2XVJxxjgTetxBHtwCwkfjeR6xL9H2DYc6Wr3vuEctxgDQUc/PLl/w)):

```
import timeit
import itertools
from itertools import repeat, chain, zip_longest
from collections import deque
from sys import hexversion, maxsize

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solution by Martijn Pieters
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def zip_equal__fillvalue__Martijn_Pieters(*iterables):
    sentinel = object()
    for combo in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel):
        if sentinel in combo:
            raise ValueError('Iterables have different lengths')
        yield combo

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solution by pylang
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def zip_equal__more_itertools__pylang(*iterables):
    return more_itertools__zip_equal(*iterables)

_marker = object()

def _zip_equal_generator(iterables):
    for combo in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=_marker):
        for val in combo:
            if val is _marker:
                raise UnequalIterablesError()
        yield combo

def more_itertools__zip_equal(*iterables):
    """``zip`` the input *iterables* together, but raise
    ``UnequalIterablesError`` if they aren't all the same length.

        >>> it_1 = range(3)
        >>> it_2 = iter('abc')
        >>> list(zip_equal(it_1, it_2))
        [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]

        >>> it_1 = range(3)
        >>> it_2 = iter('abcd')
        >>> list(zip_equal(it_1, it_2)) # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
        more_itertools.more.UnequalIterablesError: Iterables have different
        lengths

    """
    if hexversion >= 0x30A00A6:
        warnings.warn(
            (
                'zip_equal will be removed in a future version of '
                'more-itertools. Use the builtin zip function with '
                'strict=True instead.'
            ),
            DeprecationWarning,
        )
    # Check whether the iterables are all the same size.
    try:
        first_size = len(iterables[0])
        for i, it in enumerate(iterables[1:], 1):
            size = len(it)
            if size != first_size:
                break
        else:
            # If we didn't break out, we can use the built-in zip.
            return zip(*iterables)

        # If we did break out, there was a mismatch.
        raise UnequalIterablesError(details=(first_size, i, size))
    # If any one of the iterables didn't have a length, start reading
    # them until one runs out.
    except TypeError:
        return _zip_equal_generator(iterables)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solution by cjerdonek
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ExhaustedError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, index):
        """The index is the 0-based index of the exhausted iterable."""
        self.index = index

def raising_iter(i):
    """Return an iterator that raises an ExhaustedError."""
    raise ExhaustedError(i)
    yield

def terminate_iter(i, iterable):
    """Return an iterator that raises an ExhaustedError at the end."""
    return itertools.chain(iterable, raising_iter(i))

def zip_equal__chain_raising__cjerdonek(*iterables):
    iterators = [terminate_iter(*args) for args in enumerate(iterables)]
    try:
        yield from zip(*iterators)
    except ExhaustedError as exc:
        index = exc.index
        if index > 0:
            raise RuntimeError('iterable {} exhausted first'.format(index)) from None
        # Check that all other iterators are also exhausted.
        for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators[1:], start=1):
            try:
                next(iterator)
            except ExhaustedError:
                pass
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('iterable {} is longer'.format(i)) from None
            
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Solution by Stefan Pochmann
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def zip_equal__ziptail__Stefan_Pochmann(*iterables):

    # For trivial cases, use pure zip.
    if len(iterables) < 2:
        return zip(*iterables)

    # Tail for the first iterable
    first_stopped = False
    def first_tail():
        nonlocal first_stopped 
        first_stopped = True
        return
        yield

    # Tail for the zip
    def zip_tail():
        if not first_stopped:
            raise ValueError(f'zip_equal: first iterable is longer')
        for _ in chain.from_iterable(rest):
            raise ValueError(f'zip_equal: first iterable is shorter')
            yield

    # Put the pieces together
    iterables = iter(iterables)
    first = chain(next(iterables), first_tail())
    rest = list(map(iter, iterables))
    return chain(zip(first, *rest), zip_tail())

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List of solutions to be speedtested
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

solutions = [
    zip_equal__more_itertools__pylang,
    zip_equal__fillvalue__Martijn_Pieters,
    zip_equal__chain_raising__cjerdonek,
    zip_equal__ziptail__Stefan_Pochmann,
    zip,
]

def name(solution):
    return solution.__name__[11:] or 'zip'

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The speedtest code
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def test(m, n):
    """Speedtest all solutions with m iterables of n elements each."""

    all_times = {solution: [] for solution in solutions}
    def show_title():
        print(f'{m} iterators of length {n:,}:')
    if verbose: show_title()
    def show_times(times, solution):
        print(*('%3d ms ' % t for t in times),
              name(solution))
        
    for _ in range(3):
        for solution in solutions:
            times = sorted(timeit.repeat(lambda: deque(solution(*(repeat(i, n) for i in range(m))), 0), number=1, repeat=5))[:3]
            times = [round(t * 1e3, 3) for t in times]
            all_times[solution].append(times)
            if verbose: show_times(times, solution)
        if verbose: print()
        
    if verbose:
        print('best by min:')
        show_title()
        for solution in solutions:
            show_times(min(all_times[solution], key=min), solution)
        print('best by max:')
    show_title()
    for solution in solutions:
        show_times(min(all_times[solution], key=max), solution)
    print()

    stats.append((m,
                  [min(all_times[solution], key=min)
                   for solution in solutions]))

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the speedtest for several numbers of iterables
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

stats = []
verbose = False
total_elements = 2 * 10**6
for m in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 50000, 100000:
    test(m, total_elements // m)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Print the speedtest results for use in the plotting script
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print('data for plotting by https://replit.com/@pochmann/zipequal-plot')
names = [name(solution) for solution in solutions]
print(f'{names = }')
print(f'{stats = }')
```

Code for plotting/table (also [at Replit](https://replit.com/@pochmann/zipequal-plot)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ['more_itertools__pylang', 'fillvalue__Martijn_Pieters', 'chain_raising__cjerdonek', 'ziptail__Stefan_Pochmann', 'zip']
stats = [(1, [[208.762, 211.211, 214.189], [159.568, 162.233, 162.24], [57.668, 58.94, 59.23], [10.418, 10.583, 10.723], [10.057, 10.443, 10.456]]), (2, [[130.065, 130.26, 130.52], [100.314, 101.206, 101.276], [34.405, 34.998, 35.188], [12.152, 12.473, 12.773], [8.671, 8.857, 9.395]]), (3, [[106.417, 107.452, 107.668], [90.693, 91.154, 91.386], [26.908, 27.863, 28.145], [10.457, 10.461, 10.789], [8.071, 8.157, 8.228]]), (4, [[97.547, 98.686, 98.726], [77.076, 78.31, 79.381], [23.134, 23.176, 23.181], [9.321, 9.4, 9.581], [7.541, 7.554, 7.635]]), (5, [[86.393, 88.046, 88.222], [68.633, 69.649, 69.742], [19.845, 20.006, 20.135], [8.726, 8.935, 9.016], [7.201, 7.26, 7.304]]), (10, [[70.384, 71.762, 72.473], [57.87, 58.149, 58.411], [15.808, 16.252, 16.262], [7.568, 7.57, 7.864], [6.732, 6.888, 6.911]]), (100, [[53.108, 54.245, 54.465], [44.436, 44.601, 45.226], [10.502, 11.073, 11.109], [6.721, 6.733, 6.847], [6.753, 6.774, 6.815]]), (1000, [[52.119, 52.476, 53.341], [42.775, 42.808, 43.649], [12.538, 12.853, 12.862], [6.802, 6.971, 7.002], [6.679, 6.724, 6.838]]), (10000, [[54.802, 55.006, 55.187], [45.981, 46.066, 46.735], [34.416, 34.672, 35.009], [9.485, 9.509, 9.626], [9.036, 9.042, 9.112]]), (50000, [[66.681, 66.98, 67.441], [56.593, 57.341, 57.631], [113.988, 114.022, 114.106], [22.088, 22.412, 22.595], [19.412, 19.431, 19.934]]), (100000, [[86.846, 88.111, 88.258], [74.796, 75.431, 75.927], [218.977, 220.182, 223.343], [38.89, 39.385, 39.88], [32.332, 33.117, 33.594]])]

colors = {
    'more_itertools__pylang': 'm',
    'fillvalue__Martijn_Pieters': 'red',
    'chain_raising__cjerdonek': 'gold',
    'ziptail__Stefan_Pochmann': 'lime',
    'zip': 'black',
}

ns = [n for n, _ in stats]
print('%28s' % 'number of iterables', *('%5d' % n for n in ns))
print('-' * 95)
x = range(len(ns))
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    ts = [min(tss[i]) for _, tss in stats]
    color = colors[name]
    if color:
        plt.plot(x, ts, '.-', color=color, label=name)
        print('%29s' % name, *('%5.1f' % t for t in ts))
plt.xticks(x, ns, size=9)
plt.ylim(0, 133)
plt.title('zip_equal(m iterables with 2,000,000/m values each)', weight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Number of zipped *iterables* (not their lengths)', weight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Time (for complete iteration) in milliseconds', weight='bold')
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('zip_equal_plot.png', dpi=200)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Shouldn't there be a `nonlocal rest` in `zip_tail` though? (EDIT: I just went ahead and added it.)

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you?

Comment: Well, `rest` is _used_ in `zip_tail` but declared in an enclosing-but-not-`global` scope. It evidently works fine without it, but explicitly declaring the `nonlocal`-ness of `rest` seems a bit more explicit and clear to me.

Comment: Yeah, it's only needed when you *assign* to it, which I don't there. And I think that's its point, and I don't think I've ever seen people declare variables as nonlocal or global when it wasn't needed. I'd actually find that *misleading*. PEP 8 doesn't even mention`nonlocal`/`global` at all. And even you didn't declare `first_stopped`, `chain` and `ValueError` as such, even though none of them are local.

Comment: That said, it might be *faster* (not in this case, as I only access it once). I'll try to remember to test /  look into that when I'm back on a PC instead of phone.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: A microoptimization that pushes a little more work out of the Python layer: Replace the code from `iterables = iter(iterables)` through `rest = list(map(iter, iterables))` (three lines total) with the following two lines: `first, *rest = map(iter, iterables)` and `first = chain(first, first_tail())` (that second line could be inlined into the `return` line if desired). Does a little more as a bulk operation that Python provides optimized bytecodes for. Probably not worth the churn in production code, but it amuses me. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Right. Not sure why I didn't do that. Maybe I didn't want to redefine `first`. I'll leave it as is, I'd want to benchmark again even though I don't think it'll make a difference, and that's too much work :-). And people should have 3.10+ by now anyway.

Answer (score 53):

An optional boolean keyword argument, `strict`, is introduced for the built-in `zip` function in [PEP 618](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0618/).

Quoting [What’s New In Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#new-features):

> The [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip) function now has an optional `strict` flag, used to require that all the iterables have an equal length.

When enabled, a `ValueError` is raised if one of the arguments is exhausted before the others.

```
>>> list(zip('ab', range(3)))
[('a', 0), ('b', 1)]
>>> list(zip('ab', range(3), strict=True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: zip() argument 2 is longer than argument 1
```

Answer (score 32):

I can think of a simpler solution, use `itertools.zip_longest()` and raise an exception if the sentinel value used to pad out shorter iterables is present in the tuple produced:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def zip_equal(*iterables):
    sentinel = object()
    for combo in zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=sentinel):
        if sentinel in combo:
            raise ValueError('Iterables have different lengths')
        yield combo
```

Unfortunately, we can't use `zip()` with `yield from` to avoid a Python-code loop with a test each iteration; once the shortest iterator runs out, `zip()` would advance all preceding iterators and thus swallow the evidence if there is but one extra item in those.

Comment: The `yield from` solution is very nice. Thx for that and for providing two different solutions.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, in `zip_longest` the argument `fill_value` should be `fillvalue` ;-).

Comment: One thing to add: To get the iterator: `it = [iter(it) for it in iterables]`.

Comment: Oh one additional thing, the second solution doesn't work in one corner case: Assuming two iterators and the second one is shorter by one. Because zip already calls `__next__` on the first iterator both are exhausted even though the first one would be longer.

Comment: @magu_: Good catch! Indeed, I can reproduce that issue, and the second approach will have to be scrapped.

Comment: For those still in Python 2.x, you need to use `itertools.izip_longest` instead.

Comment: Also, it's probably better to replace `if sentinel in combo` with `if any(sentinel is c for c in combo)`, because `a in b` is the same as `any(bi==a for b_ in b)` - the equals is sometimes overridden (and causes an error when elements in combo are numpy arrays)

Comment: @Peter Actually `sentinel in combo` checks *both* identity *and* equality (at least nowadays :-), but yes, that's wrong if there's an element that claims to be equal to this sentinel, and numpy arrays can even make this *crash*, like `np.ones(2) in [object()]` does. The more-itertools function actually works like Martijn's but only checks identity, in a loop. That's probably the main reason it's slower, see [benchmark in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485272/1672429).

Comment: I changed my accepted answer from this answer to @StefanPochmann's answer. You have an issue with the "if sentinel in combo" (it did not affect me, but it does affect others). He offers a much thorough response and benchmark, so his answer may be more useful to future readers. (FYI)

Comment: @zeehio: that's more than fair, his solution is great!

Answer (score 7):

Use [`more_itertools.zip_equal`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.zip_equal) (v8.3.0+):

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit
```

**Demo**

```
list(mit.zip_equal(range(3), "abc"))
# [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]

list(mit.zip_equal(range(3), "abcd"))
# UnequalIterablesError
```

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) is a third party package installed via `λ pip install more_itertools`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach that doesn't require doing any extra checks with each loop of the iteration. This could be desirable especially for long iterables.

The idea is to pad each iterable with a "value" at the end that raises an exception when reached, and then do the needed verification only at the very end.  The approach uses `zip()` and `itertools.chain()`.

The code below was written for Python 3.5.

```
import itertools

class ExhaustedError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, index):
        """The index is the 0-based index of the exhausted iterable."""
        self.index = index

def raising_iter(i):
    """Return an iterator that raises an ExhaustedError."""
    raise ExhaustedError(i)
    yield

def terminate_iter(i, iterable):
    """Return an iterator that raises an ExhaustedError at the end."""
    return itertools.chain(iterable, raising_iter(i))

def zip_equal(*iterables):
    iterators = [terminate_iter(*args) for args in enumerate(iterables)]
    try:
        yield from zip(*iterators)
    except ExhaustedError as exc:
        index = exc.index
        if index > 0:
            raise RuntimeError('iterable {} exhausted first'.format(index)) from None
        # Check that all other iterators are also exhausted.
        for i, iterator in enumerate(iterators[1:], start=1):
            try:
                next(iterator)
            except ExhaustedError:
                pass
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('iterable {} is longer'.format(i)) from None
```

Below is what it looks like being used.

```
>>> list(zip_equal([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]))
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]

>>> list(zip_equal([1, 2], [3], [4]))
RuntimeError: iterable 1 exhausted first

>>> list(zip_equal([1], [2, 3], [4]))
RuntimeError: iterable 1 is longer

>>> list(zip_equal([1], [2], [3, 4]))
RuntimeError: iterable 2 is longer
```

Comment: i prefer this approach. it is a bit more complicated than the accepted answer, but it uses EAFP instead of LBYL and provides a nicer error message as well. bravo.

Comment: I edited my question with a brief discussion that points to your answer when performance is an issue. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it generates unnecessary exception even when all iterators are of same length.

Comment: You could make it a bit faster by zipping the *first* iterable *directly*, without a chained-on `raising-iter`. That is, in `terminate_iter` do `if i == 0: return iterable`. And then raise unconditionally inside `except ExhaustedError`, and unindent the `Check that all other` part one level. That said, I went a bigger step with [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485272/1672429) now.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using sentinel iterable FYI:

```
class _SentinelException(Exception):
    def __iter__(self):
        raise _SentinelException


def zip_equal(iterable1, iterable2):
    i1 = iter(itertools.chain(iterable1, _SentinelException()))
    i2 = iter(iterable2)
    try:
        while True:
            yield (next(i1), next(i2))
    except _SentinelException:  # i1 reaches end
        try:
            next(i2)  # check whether i2 reaches end
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError('the second iterable is longer than the first one')
    except StopIteration: # i2 reaches end, as next(i1) has already been called, i1's length is bigger than i2
        raise ValueError('the first iterable is longger the second one.')
```

Comment: What advantage does this solution offer with respect to the accepted solution?

Comment: Just an alternative solution. For me, as I am from C++ world, I don't like the "if sentinel in combo" check for each yield. But as we are in python world, no one cares about performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if you were really concerned about performance you should have benchmarked it. Your solution is 80% slower. Here is a benchmark: https://gist.github.com/zeehio/cdf7d881cc7f612b2c853fbd3a18ccbe

Comment: Thank you for your kind benchmark. Sorry for the misleading. Yes, it is slower, I should think out earlier, as izip_longest is native.

Comment: Sorry if I was harsh in my reply. Thanks to your answer we compared the performances. We found that the accepted answer is faster than the other solutions. We now also have a quick way to benchmark any future solution. We know more now than one week ago. :-)

Comment: @zeehio You said you found that the accepted answer is faster than the other solutions, but your gist didn't include my solution. When I added my solution, it was 20% faster than the accepted one. Also, when I increased the length from 100 to 10,000, mine was over 40% faster. Intuitively, the reason is that the implementation I proposed doesn't require doing any checks with each loop of the iteration.

Comment: Good to know that your solution is faster. I should have said "than the accepted solution" in my previous comment instead. My apologies :-S As I mentioned in the question, I was interested on simplicity and in that aspect Martin's solution is better. I just checked the performance of this answer because of the "no one cares about perfomance" comment, I should have included yours.