# Specifying arguments in a function from a list

Tags: python, pandas, argument-unpacking

I've read up on a number of threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480184/unpack-a-list-in-python)) and the docs ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)). However, I can't get this to work. I get an error of

```
AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import levene

data = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        'B': [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16],
        'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B','C'])

print(levene(df3['A'], df3['C'])) # this works as intended

cols_of_interest = ['A','C'] # my requirement could make this any combination

# function to pass through arguments into Levene test
def func(df,cols_of_interest):
    cols = [col for col in 'df.'+df[cols_of_interest].columns] # my strategy to mimic the arguments
    lev = levene(*cols)
    print(lev)

func(df3,cols_of_interest)
```

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your list comprehension inside `def` with:

```
cols = [df[x] for x in cols_of_interest]
```