# How can I make a class instance from a list?

Tags: python, list, class, oop, typeerror

I have been trying to make something like this:

```
class Numbers:
    def __init__(self,one,two):
        self.one = one
        self.two = two

numb_list = ["three","four"]

num = Numbers(i for i in numb_list)
```

but I get a TypeError. So, is there a way I can make a new class instance from a list, tuple or a dictionary?

Comment: `num = Numbers(*[i for i in numb_list])` Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python

Comment: `num = Numbers(*numb_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unpack them using `*` and pass them.

```
num = Numbers(*numb_list)
num.one
# 'three'
num.two
# 'four'
```