# Passing arguments for user selected function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two user defined functions, like this:

```
def test_sum(a,b):
    x = a+b
    return x

def test_mean(a,b,c):
    z = a+b+c
    return z
```

using dictionary, based on the user interest one of the function is selected

```
func = {
    'sum_test': test_sum,
    'mean_test': test_mean
}

user_input = 'sum_test'

if user_input in func:
    print(func[user_input](10, 15))
```

How to pass the function arguments dynamically similar to how function is selected by user? (For the `test_sum` function I know there are two arguments so I gave `10, 15`, but for the `test_mean` function there are three arguments so I have to change `10, 15` to `10, 15, 20` and I have to do this every time when a function changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are three ways to solve your problem. The first and cleaner one is to use iterables such as a list:

```
def test_sum(vals):
    return sum(vals)

def test_mean(vals):
    return test_sum(vals)/len(vals)

func = {
    'sum_test': test_sum,
    'mean_test': test_mean
}

user_input = 'sum_test'

if user_input in func:
    print(func[user_input]([10, 15]))
```

Note that the `[10, 15]` creates a list object containing the values 10 and 15.

If using iterables is not an option (for instance because your functions expect non-uniform inputs) you follow mkrieger1's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817087/call-a-function-with-argument-list-in-python).

A third alternative is using a dictionary. You can find an example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-passing-dictionary-as-arguments-to-function/) if you go to the section "Passing Dictionary as kwargs".