# learn python the hard way exercise 18 help

Tags: python

i understand all the functions except the first one. whats the (*args) mean?

thanks

```
def print_twice(*args):
    arg1, arg2 = args
    print 'arg1: %r arg2: %r' % (arg1, arg2)

def print_twice_again(arg1, arg2):
    print 'arg1: %r arg2: %r' % (arg1, arg2)

def print_once(arg1):
    print 'arg1: %r' % arg1

def print_none():
    print 'i got nothin...'

print_twice("neil", "harper")
print_twice_again("neil", "harper")
print_once("first!")
print_none()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does *args and **kwargs mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does ** and * do for python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-and-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 5):

One asterix specifies a list, two asterixes specify a dictionary.

Comment: so *args makes a list called args? what defines how many values it can hold?

Comment: @neil: It can hold any number of values. So `print_twice(1,2,3,4,5)` will pass a list with 5 parameters in `args`.