# Lambda and functions in Python

Tags: python

I have beginner two questions

1. What does `*z` or `*foo` or `**foo` mean regarding function in Python.
2. This works - `a = lambda *z :z` But this does not - `a = lambda **z: z`. Because it is supposed to take 0 arguments. What does this actually mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218993/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-18-help/5219071#5219071

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`*z` and `**z` in Python refer to args and kwargs. args are positional arguments and kwargs are keyword arguments. lambda `**z` doesn't work in your example because `z` isn't a keyword argument: it's merely positional. Compare these different results:

```
    >>> a = lambda z: z
    >>> b = lambda *z: z
    >>> c = lambda **z: z
    >>> a([1,2,3])
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> b([1,2,3])
    ([1, 2, 3],)
    >>> c([1,2,3]) # list arg passed, **kwargs expected
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
    >>> c(z=[1,2,3]) # explicit kwarg
    {'z': [1, 2, 3]}
    >>> c(x=[1,2,3]) # explicit kwarg
    {'x': [1, 2, 3]}
    >>> c({'x':[1,2,3]}) # dict called as a single arg
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
    >>> c(**{'x':[1,2,3]}) # dict called as **kwargs
    {'x': [1, 2, 3]}
    >>> b(*[1,2,3]) # list called as *args
    (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the link its a good blog post on How to use *args and **kwargs in Python 
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Answer (score 4):

When you see something like `def foo(*args)` or `def foo(**kwargs)` they're telling you they're expecting something more than a single argument.  They're expecting several arguments or several named arguments.  Often, however, you see this:

```
def foo(item1, item2, item3, *args, **kwargs)
```

Which tells you that they're expecting at least item's 1, 2, and 3 but "args" and "kwargs" are optional parameters.

To answer your question regarding `a = lambda **z: z` try passing in a "named argument list" like so:

```
> a = lambda **z:z
> a(b=1, c=2)
>> {b : 1, c : 2}
```

The output will be a dictionary, just as you inadvertently defined.  Named argument lists are, in essence, dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

`*args` can be used to make a function take an arbitrary number of arguments. `**kwargs` can be used to make a function take arbitrary keyword arguments. This means that:

```
>>> foo = lambda *args: args
>>> bar = lambda **kwargs: kwargs
>>> foo(1,2,3)
(1,2,3)
>>> bar(asdf=1)
{'asdf':1}
>>> bar(1,2,3)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 0 arguments (3 given)
```

The last error happens because `bar` can only take keyword arguments.

Comment: Does `foo(1, 2, 3)` really produce a list for you?  It gives a tuple here.

Comment: Sorry, hasty there. It is actually a tuple. Thanks.