# Django with argument **kwargs

Tags: python, django, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean)
>   [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

I've found some strange syntax in Django framework like:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

My question is: what does the star means in the name of the argument. Is there anything with pointer in C?
Thanks

Comment: Read about them here: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: also read similar questions e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you call save using these arguments:

```
save(1,2,3,4,a=20,b=30,c=40)
```

then `args` will be equal to `(1,2,3,4)` i.e. a `Tuple` 
and `kwargs` will be equal to `{'a':20,'b':30,'c':40}` a `dictionary`

these * and ** notations are used for collecting arguments in Python , they are not Pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a python arguments syntax:

- *args - list of unnamed arguments
- **kwargs - dictionary (named arguments)