# django admin custom commands - passing a list of strings into args

Tags: python, django

I have a list of strings which I would like to pass into args in my django custom command.

```
list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', etc...]
```

How can I do this from within a python function:

```
management.call_command('commandname', args, options)
```

I've tired passing on my list of args both:

[1] directly:

```
    management.call_command('commandname', list)
```

and

[2] as a loop:

```
    management.call_command('commandname', (abc for abc in list))
```

but both have failed after entering the custom command

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The call_command method is using [Arbitrary Arguments List](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) for command arguments.

So, you need to use:

```
list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
management.call_command('commandname', *list)
```

Which is the same than:

```
management.call_command('commandname', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi')
```

Related information:

- [What does *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean)
- [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Can you give a example using what I've specified above? Sorry this just isn't very helpful without an example.

Comment: Another example: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/#calling-a-function

Comment: Just call it like this: `management.call_command('commandname', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi')`

Comment: Is there a **max** number of args for a django command? I have a list of 500 args and it's crashing at the end. A test with 10 args worked perfectly.

Comment: @thong i just tried to pass 10^7 *args and 10^7 *kwargs to a normal python function and it still worked. not sure about django functions peculiarities though.