# Python Lambda Function Invalid Argument

Tags: python, api, lambda

I am creating objects that I will eventually graph and using an api for the data.
For the object attribute that I intend to graph, I am using a lambda function so that it will return the particular data I need for each new object.

The Lambda function passes two arguments through the api call, the first `a`, references the objects `.name` attribute, and works perfectly. When I try to reference the second lambda argument `b` which references the objects `.time` attribute, I get an error `b is an invalid key argument for __new__()`

```
default = 'USD'
asset1_input = 'ETH'
asset2_input = 'DAI'


class Asset:
    def __init__(self, name, time, allocate, perform):
        self.name = name
        self.time = time
        self.allocate = allocate
        self.perform = perform(name, time)[name][default]

perform = lambda a, b : cryptocompare.get_historical_price(a, 'USD', datetime.today() - timedelta(b=5))


asset1 = Asset(asset1_input, 'days', .2, perform)

print(asset1.perform)
```

`datetime` is expecting days or weeks. If I manually put one of these in then it works fine. Part of the problem may be that datetime isn't expecting a string `days`, its just expecting days, however when I put days in as the value for time, I get `days undefined`. Was considering an `if` statement and a `for` loop in the lambda function (`if some input == 'days'`, and a `for` loop to iterate the `days` value) however other stack posts mentioned that you cant iterate with a for loop in lambda function.

Comment: You may as well make `perform` a normal boring old function because a) then you can debug it, and b) you can add if/for/whatever control flow you need. But otherwise show the full error message including stack trace and the source code covering that if not already in your question.

Comment: Your question is unclear - you should really consider creating a [mre]. But maybe what you mean is what is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441779/550094 (I'm sure there are better duplicates somewhere, but I fail to find any right now...)

Comment: @barny `perform` *is* a normal boring old function. It's just defined (inadvisedly) using a lambda expression instead of a `def` statement.