# How to pass a method that receives parameters as a parameter of another function in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I know this is valid:

```
def printValue():
    print 'This is the printValue() method'

def callPrintValue(methodName):
    methodName()
    print 'This is the callPrintValue() method'
```

but is there a way to pass a method that receives parameters as a parameter of another function?

Doing this is not possible:

```
def printValue(value):
    print 'This is the printValue() method. The value is %s'%(value)

def callPrintValue(methodName):
    methodName()
    print 'This is the callPrintValue() method'
```

This is the stack trace i get:

```
This is the printValue() method. The value is dsdsd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in callPrintValue
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def printValue(value):
    print 'This is the printValue() method. The value is %s'%(value)

def callPrintValue(methodName, *args):
    methodName(*args)
    print 'This is the callPrintValue() method'
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
callPrintValue(printValue, "Value to pass to printValue")
```

This allows you to pass in an arbitrary number of arguments, and all of them are passed to the function that you call in `callPrintValue`

Answer (score 8):

Some people find `lambda` ugly, but it is a useful tool in cases like this. Rather than modifying the signature of `callPrintValue()`, you can use `lambda` to quickly define a new function that binds the arguments to `printValue()`. Whether you really want to do this depends on many factors, and it may be that adding an `*args` parameter as others have suggested is preferable. Still, this is an option worth considering. The following works with no modifications to your current code:

```
>>> callPrintValue(lambda: printValue('"Hello, I am a value"'))
This is the printValue() method. The value is "Hello, I am a value"
This is the callPrintValue() method
```

Comment: I agree that `lambda` may be what is called for here (+1).  In fact, this is how it is often done in GUI programming (with `tkinter` for example) as there you don't have any way to modify the function doing the callback.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can do this

```
def callPrintValue(methodName, *args):
    methodName(*args)
    print 'This is the callPrintValue() method'
```

make the call

```
callPrintValue(printValue, "abc")
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use tuple unpacking:

```
def print_value(*values):
    print values

def call_print_value(func,args=None):
    func(*args)

call_print_value(print_value,args=('this','works')) #prints ('this', 'works')
```

From an API point of view, I prefer to keep the arguments that are passed on as a separate keyword.  (then it's a little more explicit which arguments are being used by `print_value` and which ones are being used by `call_print_value`).  Also note that in python, it is customary to have function (and method) names as `name_with_underscores`.  CamelCase is generally used for class names.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to the answers provided already, you may want to check out the the following questions on stackoverflow for a better understanding of *args and/or **kwargs and `lambda` in python.

1. [What does *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-does-args-and-kwargs-mean)
2. [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for python parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)
3. [Python Lambda - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why)