# How to convert single dictonary with list as key values into list of dictonaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```py
my_dict = {'index':[1,2,3], 'answer':['A','D','B']}
```

**I want to convert this `my_dict` into this below list**

```py
[{'index': 1,'answer': 'A'}, {'index':2, 'answer': 'D'}, {'index': 3, 'answer': 'B'}]
```

**I have the solution but it depends upon `pandas` library, but I am looking for a way to do it without any dependencies**

##### `pandas` solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
output = list(pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T.to_dict().values())
output

[{'index': 1, 'answer': 'A'},
 {'index': 2, 'answer': 'D'},
 {'index': 3, 'answer': 'B'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer:

```
[{'index': x, 'answer': y} for x, y in zip(*my_dict.values())]
```

Or if you care about order:

```
[{k: ip[i] for i, k in enumerate(my_dict)} for ip in zip(*my_dict.values())]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'index': 1, 'answer': 'A'}, {'index': 2, 'answer': 'D'}, {'index': 3, 'answer': 'B'}]
```

Or as @Jab mentioned, you could use:

```
[dict(zip(my_dict, ip)) for ip in zip(*my_dict.values())]
```

Direct zipping.

Comment: Can also be done without specifying the keys using: `[dict(zip(my_dict, ip)) for ip in zip(*my_dict.values())]`

Comment: Yeah, this does the trick! What does `*` do here? I tried without it, and it didn't work. What does this expression call by?

Comment: @AdityaRajgor It's unpacking! Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236023/what-is-the-asterisk-in-replacesomething-for-python) out.

Comment: Your solution would fail if the key `index` does not come before `answer` in the  input dict, which is not guaranteed by the OP. @Jab's answer on the other hand would work regardless of the order of the keys since the order of values returned by the `values` method will always correspond to their respective keys yielded by the dict's key generator.

Comment: @blhsing Yes. But the OP doesn't specify anything about that... I am answering this based on the OP's question... Anyway, added another solution...

Comment: Anything not mentioned by the OP cannot be assumed. You should simply remove your solution from your answer as it is based on an inappropriate assumption.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for this example. Let me know if you wanted something more general.

```
[
  {'index': index, 'answer': answer}
  for index, answer in zip(my_dict['index'], my_dict['answer'])
]
```