# Python wrap function with unknown arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

If I have this function:

```
def foo(arg_one, arg_two):
    pass
```

I can wrap it like so:

```
def bar(arg_one, arg_two):
    return foo(arg_one, arg_two)

foo = bar
```

Is it possible to do this without knowing foo's required arguments, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
def bar(*args, **kwargs):
    return foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

`args` is a list of positional arguments.

`kwargs` is a dictionary of keyword arguments.

Note that calling those variables `args` and `kwargs` is just a naming convention. `*` and `**` do all the magic for unpacking the arguments.

Also see:

- [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)
- [What do *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean)
- [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: Ah, thank you, I thought **kwargs might be related, but I didn't know about *args, so couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the argument unpacking operators (or whatever [they're called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322355/proper-name-for-python-operator)):

```
def bar(*args, **kwargs):
    return foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you don't plan on passing any keyword arguments, you can remove `**kwargs`.

Comment: doesn't hurt to leave it though, it might come in handy later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another slightly general use case (in addition to answer by Blender):

Typically in OOP when extending objects, one actually needs to **override a method and (carefully) extend or even change the signature** (order and number of arguments of the extended method), e.g. in `__init__()` methods which are object constructors.

Here is an example how to apply *args, **kwds for this purpose:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init(self, foo_positional_arg, foo_optional_arg=None):
        pass


class Bar(Foo):

    def __init__(self, bar_postional_arg, bar_optional_arg=None, *args, **kwds):
        self.bar_postional_arg = bar_postional_arg
        self.bar_optional_arg = bar_optional_arg
        super(Bar, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
```

In fact one can actually indeed change the order of the signature or trap the arguments from the previous (wrapped) full or partial signature.

```
def __init__(self, bar_postional_arg, foo_positional, foo_optional_arg=False, bar_optional_arg=None, *args, **kwds):
```

This proves again how extremely flexible(!) is the *args, **kwds mechanism in python functions (and methods).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328273/7262247), if you wish your wrapper to preserve the signature (in other words to appear to its users as if it were the wrapped function), you may wish to have a look at `functools.wraps` and its replacement `makefun.wraps`, that fixes a few shortcomings and extends its usage to cases where you would like to modify the signature. See [here](https://smarie.github.io/python-makefun/#signature-preserving-function-wrappers) for a short explanation of the difference. I am the author of `makefun` by the way ;)

This is how you would code it:

```
from makefun import wraps

@wraps(foo)
def bar(*args, **kwargs):
    return foo(*args, **kwargs)
```