# Count number of strings

Tags: python

First of all, I do realize that this is a really simple question and please bear with me on this.

How, in python, can I get the numbers of strings? I am trying to do something like this:

```
def func(input_strings):
    # Make the input_strings iterable
    if len(input_strings) == 1:
        input_strings = (input_strings, )
    # Do something
    for input_string in input_strings:
        analyze_string(input_string)
    return
```

So with this function, if the input is a list, ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'], it will loop over them; if the input is only one string like 'string1', then it will still take care of it, instead of throwing an exception.

However, the len(str) returns the number of characters in the string and wouldn't give me a "1".

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is there a separator between the strings -- a comma, a line break, a tab, something?

Comment: @hughdbrown Thanks for making me realize that the question is vague... I'll edit it right away.

Comment: try replacing `if len(input_strings) == 1:` with `if type(input_strings) == str:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check whether a given value is string:

```
>>> isinstance('a-string', str)
True
>>> isinstance(['a-string', 'another-string'], str)
False
```

---

```
def func(input_strings):
    # Make the input_strings iterable
    if isinstance(input_strings, str):
        input_strings = (input_strings, )
    # Do something
    for input_string in input_strings:
        analyze_string(input_string)
    return
```

**Python 2.x note (Python 2.3+)**

Use `isinstance('a-string', basestring)` if you want to also test unicode. ([`basestring`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring) is the superclass for `str` and `unicode`).

Comment: But in python2 when the input_string is unicode it will be wrong, so you should use `basestring` but not `str`, such as: `isinstance(a_string, basestring)`

Comment: @atupal, I mentioned that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `*args` to allow the function to accept any number of strings.

```
def func(*input_strings):
    for input_string in input_strings:
        analyze_string(input_string)

func("one string")
func("lots", "of", "strings")
```

If you then want the number of strings, you can simple use `len(input_strings)`.

Have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean).