# What is the role of "*" inside of a Python3 print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the role of "*" inside of a print function in Python?

```
print ("Hello World!\n")
print (*"Hello World!\n")
```

Output of the first print function is

```
 Hello World!
```

Output of the second function is

```
H e l l o   W o r l d !
```

**But in python 2.7 it does not work!**

Comment: This doesn't apply *just* to the `print()` function but to *all* function calls.

Comment: Also see [What do \*args and \*\*kwargs mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/287085)

Comment: This only works for function calls, not for statements. In Python 3, `print` is not a statement, but a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` unpacks the sequence given, for example:

```
>>> print(*[1, 2, 3])
1 2 3
```

Here, it *unpacks* the list and prints out each individual item.

In your example, as strings are also a sequence, it prints out each letter separated by a space. Think of the string `"Hello world!"` as `['H', 'e', 'l', etc]`