# Using PyAudio libraries in Python (Linux)

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a method of PyAudio library, I am suppose to change the default input device since I have connected a USB based Mic to my Laptop and not using the builtin MIC, but I am facing issues doing so,

Here is the complete details of the method,

```
Help on method open in module pyaudio:

open(self, *args, **kwargs) method of pyaudio.PyAudio instance
    Open a new stream. See constructor for
    :py:func:`Stream.__init__` for parameter details.

    :returns: A new :py:class:`Stream`
```

.

```
class pyaudio.Stream(PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input=False, output=False, input_device_index=None, output_device_index=None, frames_per_buffer=1024, start=True, input_host_api_specific_stream_info=None, output_host_api_specific_stream_info=None, stream_callback=None)
PortAudio Stream Wrapper.
```

Use `PyAudio.open()` to make a new Stream.

```
__init__(PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input=False, output=False, input_device_index=None, output_device_index=None, frames_per_buffer=1024, start=True, input_host_api_specific_stream_info=None, output_host_api_specific_stream_info=None, stream_callback=None)
```

Initialize a stream; this should be called by 
`PyAudio.open()`. A stream can either be input, output, or both.

What I want to do is to use

```
PyAudio.open()
```

method and set the value of `input_device_index=` to `1`

But I couldn't understand how to pass the arguments in this function and how to use this **init** ?

What I have already tried is,

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
p.open(__init__(input_device_index=1))
```

But it gives the error.

Here is the complete documentation of the methods,
init">http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.**init**

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean

Comment: my question is much more specific than simply asking about args and kwargs

Comment: Xufyan, you could be more specific in question because now it's a little misleading. If I understand it correctly you are asking how to use PyAudio.open method (how to use library) rather then how to implement a function.

Comment: I am desperately sorry for any inconvenience caused, I have fixed the question , hopefully it is not irritating now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args` will let any positional arguments be passed to the function as list.

`**kwargs` will let any associative arguments be passed to the function as dict.

Example:

```
def a(*args,**kwargs):
     print args
     print kwargs

a('abc','75449',test=None,abc=-1)
```

Prints:

```
['abc','75449']
{'test':None,'abc':-1}
```

Comment: I think this is not what Xufyan asks for. It's about pyaudio rather then python itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
p.open(__init__(input_device_index=1))
```

Makes no sense because `__init__` is not defined. `PyAudio.__init__` is called by initialising `PyAudio`, so that would be

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio(input_device_index=1)
p.open()
```

although it seems that `open` passes all its attributes through, using `*args` and `**kwargs`, so it might be

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
p.open(input_device_index=1)
```

Anything more precise than that will require a better question or experience with PyAudio, neither of which I have.