# python reduce to find the union of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, set, fold

I am trying to find the union of set of sets. Specifically I want the union of the list of nodes for each key in the dictionary of `networkx` graphs called `periodic_gs`. I would like to use the `reduce` function as it seems reasonable to take the union of all `periodic_gs[x].nodes()`  where `x` is a key of `periodic_gs`.

Here is my attempt:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: set(periodic_gs[x].nodes()).union(set(periodic_gs[y].nodes())), periodic_gs.keys(), {})
```

To me, this says take the union of the nodes across each graph in the dictionary. For some reason, python tells me: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` I do not see this `TypeError`, because `periodic_gs.keys()` is a list of the keys (they are strings but I do not see how this would matter), and when substituted in for the arguments to the lambda function will work.

What is causing the type error and how do I fix it?

Comment: `union of set of sets`: A set can't contain another set.

Comment: Post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) like this:

```
>>> lis = [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {7, 3, 6}]
>>> set().union(*lis)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

It's possible to do this using [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), but **don't**:

```
>>> reduce(set.union, lis)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

because this `reduce` takes quadratic time due to all the intermediate sets it builds and discards:

```
In [1]: from functools import reduce

In [2]: sets = [{x} for x in range(1000)]

In [3]: %timeit set().union(*sets)
40.9 µs ± 1.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit reduce(set.union, sets)
4.09 ms ± 587 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That's a 100x slowdown on this test case, and it can easily be even worse.

For your code, this should do it:

```
set().union(*(x.nodes() for x in periodic_gs.values()))
```

Comment: There is no need to use `union()`, though. Not for a sequence of sequences and an empty starting `set()`.

Comment: Where is the documentation for *?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus [What do *args and **kwargs mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean)

Comment: @ChaimG I provided an answer too.

Answer (score 5):

`{}` is an empty *dictionary*, not a set. Use `set()` to create an empty set.

However, I think you are misinterpreting how `reduce()` works here; `x` is the *previous* return value of the `lambda`, and `y` is the next value from the sequence. Because you return a set, `x` is always a set here, and you cannot use that as a key to `periodic_gs`.

If you want the union of *all* nodes in the graph, use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and `set()`:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable(periodic_gs[key].nodes() for key in periodic_gs))
```

This creates *one* set from each of the `nodes()` calls.

To use `reduce()` you'd have to take into account that the first argument is always a set:

```
reduce(lambda res, key: res.union(periodic_gs[key].nodes()),  periodic_gs, set())
```

I am assuming here that `periodic_gs` is iterable (yielding keys) just like a regular dictionary; if not, use `periodic_gs.keys()`.

A quick demo with a regular dictionary:

```
>>> example = {'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar': [3, 4, 1]}
>>> reduce(lambda res, key: res.union(example[key]), example, set())
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: It says `unhashable type: set` now.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: You are using the reduce wrong too; the output is always a set, but you then assume `x` is something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  The initializer you supplied to `reduce`, `{}`, is an empty `dict`, and not a `set` as you seem to be assuming, thus leading to the first type error.  However, even after you fix this, there's still a bigger problem: the `lambda` evaluates to a `set` object containing nodes, and this `set` is then used as the `x` value for the next call to the `lambda`, which tries to use it as as though it were a key of `periodic_gs`, thereby causing the second type error.  To top it all off, there's no point in iterating over the keys of a `dict` if you're only going to use them to access the values; just iterate over the values in the first place!  There's *also* no point in converting a bunch of lists to sets and then taking their union when you could just chain them all together and take the union of the result.

I would recommend rewriting the code entirely as:

```
set(n for val in periodic_gs.values() for n in val.nodes())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce to get the union of multiple sets as shown here:

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = set([1, 3, 5])
>>> b = set([2, 4, 6])
>>> c = set([0, 7, 8])
>>> reduce(operator.or_, [a, b, c])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `set` of `set` because elements of `set` need to be hashable. You can make a `set` of `frozenset` however.

```
{frozenset(n) for val in periodic_gs.values() for n in val.nodes()}
```