# Can't create instance with string variable due to arg error

Tags: python, string, class

I have a python 2.6 class called Film:

```
class Film(Video):
    def __init__(self, title, yt_link, year):
        Video.__init__(self, title, yt_link)
        self.year = year
```

and also, I have a variable `result` which stores the string:

```
result = 'Toy Story','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPhse4WlgEA','1995'
```

When I try to create an instance of the class:

```
toy_story = Film(result)
```

I get an error:

```
__init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

However, when I input the string directly to Film(), there is no error.

How can I make it so that `Film(result)` might resolve the arguments error?

Comment: I think it's good practice to enclose tuples like that in parentheses, even if Python would do it for you automatically. That prevents this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you understand [tuples](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html) and [the star operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean), consider this:

instead of doing

```
toy_story = Film(*result)
```

(as suggested by mgilson)

you *could* also do

```
toy_story = Film(result[0], result[1], result[2])
```

So, tuples can be treated kind of like a mini array.

---

Note: this isn't a better solution. It's only intended to be more readable for programmers unfamiliar with the star operator and tuples.

Answer (score 2):

`result` is a tuple.  Currently you're passing the whole tuple to the first positional argument (`title`).  Instead, you need to unpack the tuple using the "splat" or "unpacking" or "star" operator (it has a bunch of names):

```
toy_story = Film(*result)
```