# Stacking lists into arrays in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to work out how to add multiple lists to an array. Following is what I've come up with but it's not working.

```
import math
import numpy as np

myList1 = [1,2,'nan']
myList2 = [3,4,5]

class myThing(object):
    def __init__(self, myLists=[]): #This could accept 1 or many lists
    self.__myVars = np.array(myLists, dtype=float)
    self.__myVars.shape = (len(myLists),3)
    self.__myVars = np.vstack(myVars)

        @property
    def myVars(self):
        return self.__myVars

foo = myThing(myList1,myList2)
print foo.myVars

blah blah...
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use `*myLists`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287085/190597) in `def __init__` to allow `__init__` to accept an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def __init__(self, *myLists): #This could accept 1 or many lists
```

---

```
import numpy as np

myList1 = [1,2,'nan']
myList2 = [3,4,5]

class myThing(object):
    def __init__(self, *myLists): #This could accept 1 or many lists
        self.__myVars = np.array(myLists, dtype=float)

    @property
    def myVars(self):
        return self.__myVars

foo = myThing(myList1,myList2)
print foo.myVars
```

yields

```
[[  1.   2.  nan]
 [  3.   4.   5.]]
```

---

Also, when debugging errors, it's useful to look at more than the exception itself. The full traceback includes the line on which the Exception occurred:

```
---> 20 foo = myThing(myList1,myList2)
     21 print foo.myVars

TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

This can help clue us in to what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
def __init__(self, *myLists): #This could accept 1 or many lists
```