# How to pass list elements as arguments

Tags: python

I want to pass elements of list as function arguments like this:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    # do something

list = [1, 2, 3]
foo(list)
```

I can't use `foo(list[0], list[1], list[2])`, because I don't know how many elements the list has and how many arguments the function takes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [the `*` argument unpacking operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287085/190597):

```
seq = [1, 2, 3]
foo(*seq)
```

So in [the `input` function](http://pastebin.com/ajDrFmzr) you could use

```
getattr(self, func)(*args)
```

---

PS. Don't name your variables `list`, since it shadows the built-in of the same name.