# Passing a list of items to multiprocessing function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following function:

```
def create_job(target, args):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=args)
    p.start()
    return p
```

The above function gets called by:

```
ps = create_job(mc.collect_categories, (cat_ids),)
```

Being cat_ids a list of 'ids': ['ML68', 'MA453','MA33']

When I run the code I get the following error(with a list of 10 cat_ids):

```
TypeError: collect_categories() takes exactly 2 arguments (11 given)
```

I tried to pass the values with the '*' to unpack it but that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(cat_ids)` is identical to `cat_ids`.
Instead use `(cat_ids, )` to denote a tuple with one element:

```
ps = create_job(mc.collect_categories, (cat_ids, ),)
```

---

Alternatively, you could define `create_job` [using `*args`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287085/190597):

```
def create_job(target, *args):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=args)
    p.start()
    return p
```

and call `create_job` with:

```
ps = create_job(mc.collect_categories, cat_ids)
```

Inside `create_job`, the variable `args` will be a tuple of all the positional arguments (except the first) passed to `create_job` -- exactly what you want to pass to `Process`.