# More Pythonic way to turn any number of different lists or tuples into one list

Tags: python, list, args

I am trying to write a function to take in any number of different lists or tuples as arguments and return one big list.

```
def addify(*args):
    big_list = list()
    for iterable in args:
        if isinstance(iterable, tuple):
            big_list.extend(list(iterable))
        else:
            big_list.extend(iterable)
    return big_list

>>> print addify((1,2,3), [2, 5, 3], (3,1,3), [3, 2344, 3])
[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2344, 3]
```

I was learning about [args and kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean), and my code is working all right, but this seems like too much code for something so simple.

There must be a better way than writing a long function to check if an argument is a tuple and if it is add convert it to a list and then add it on. That just seems bloated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is what you are looking for:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> print list(chain((1,2,3), [2, 5, 3], (3,1,3), [3, 2344, 3]))
[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2344, 3]
```

*Note: Calling `list` is necessary if you want a list instead of a `itertools.chain` object.*

Comment: This works for tuples and lists mixed?

Comment: @FinNewt Yes. The performance of `chain` is identical to what you were describing.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is already included in Python via [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def addify(*args):
...     return list(chain(*args))
... 
>>> addify((1,2,3), [2, 5, 3], (3,1,3), [3, 2344, 3])
[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2344, 3]
```

That, or as @Navith said, you could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def addify(*args):
...     return list(chain.from_iterable(args))
... 
>>> addify((1,2,3), [2, 5, 3], (3,1,3), [3, 2344, 3])
[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2344, 3]
```

Note however that you need to call `list()` on both because they return iterators by default:

```
>>> chain((1,2,3), [2, 5, 3], (3,1,3), [3, 2344, 3])
<itertools.chain object at 0x04829390>
>>> chain.from_iterable([(1,2,3), [2, 5, 3], (3,1,3), [3, 2344, 3]])
<itertools.chain object at 0x048293D0>
```

Which might actually be a good thing if you do not need all of the items right up front.

Comment: Jinx Dude :-\. But do you really need to put the call to chain in a function?

Comment: No, you can just do `list(chain(...))`.  I was only keeping the OP's function so the example was clearer.

Comment: [`chain.from_iterable(iterables)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) is preferable to `chain(*iterables)` for potentially infinite iterators.

Comment: @Navith - I was actually just about to add `chain.from_iterable` to my answer.  Thanks for the tip though. :)