# More than one tuple *args

Tags: python

I know you can use `*args` in Python to allow a tuple or arguments. But how could one have two of these. Like `*args` and `*args1`?

Is this possible?

Comment: Then what do you want to get? What do you want `*args1` be?

Comment: Also if you just try it, you can get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: Short answer, **no**.

Comment: How would you differentiate `*args` and `args1` you can't. So as jim stated  **no**

Comment: You probably need to read up on python function arguments in more detail for what these mean.  The short answer, though, is that when you see a function defined like `def f(*args)` python just takes all extra positional arguments and creates a tuple to hold them.  If you want a function taking multiple tuples you can explicitly define such like `f(x1,x2)` where `x1` and `x2` are tuples.  The star-ed form is simply for when you need any number of arguments and can't specify how many before hand.  It doesn't mean a tuple, but "everything I haven't specifed".

Comment: What are you trying to do with such a syntax? Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean in terms of function arguments, then no it isn't possible. The reason why is a tuple `*args` can be of any length of 0 or more arguments. If you had another one, `*args2`, how would you determined which arguments belong to `*args` and which to `*args2`? You can however include a `**kwargs` which is a dictionary object of keyword arguments. For example:

```
def my_function(x, *args):
    ...
```

You can figure out what the args of `*args` are. However, in

```
def my_function2(x, *args, *args):
    ...
```

You cannot determine which arguments go into `args1` and which go into `*args2`. However, for

```
def my_function3(x, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

It's possible to differentiate the arguments that belong to `*args` and those that belong to `**kwargs` because the arguments that belong to the `**kwargs` take the form of `arg = val`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple variadic parameters of the same type in a function definition (e.g. `def func(*args, *args1)`, but, [in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448), you can pass arguments in that form when calling a function.

Python 3.4:

```
>>> print(*range(3), *range(3))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(*range(3), *range(3))
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python 3.5:

```
>>> print(*range(3), *range(3))
0 1 2 0 1 2
```

Comment: I see now. Kwargs is a dictionary. Okay. Meaning I can run

Comment: "Kwargs" isn't a dictionary - any name preceded by `**`, syntax permitting, represents an unpacked dictionary. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean?rq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs?rq=1) for more.

Comment: I see now. Kwargs is a dictionary. Okay. Meaning I can run: `def swag(**kwargs): print(kwargs["name"]` with `swag(name="Tristan")` which will print out Tristan then.

Comment: Oh okay. So I can do **swag and use it as a dictionary. What is an unpacked dictionary. Does ** make it a dictionary without having to do d = {}

Comment: Yes, that `swag()` example would work (I encourage you to experiment with the interpreter). An unpacked dictionary looks like `swag(name='Tristan')`, which is different from sending in an actual dictionary with `swag({'name':'Tristan'})`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass `*args` twice when calling a function (up until in [Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448))

```
>>> fun(*a, *b)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    fun(*a, *b)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, what you *can* do is concatenate two `args` (`list` or `tuple`) as you pass them using `+`. For example:

```
>>> def fun(*args):
...    print(args)
...
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [6,7,8,9]
>>>
>>> fun(*a)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> fun(*b)
(6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> fun(*a+b)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

The function definition can only have a single `*args` definition, and all passed position arguments will end up in the `args` variable in the order they were passed.