# How to apply '*args' and '*kwargs' to define a `class`

Tags: python

For the ease of further scale, I define a class `Book` with `args` and 'kwargs'.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            self.name,\
            self.author,\
            = args
        elif kwargs:
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

It works well respectively with positional and keywords arguments

```
In [62]: book1 = Book('Python', 'Guido')
In [63]: book1.author
Out[63]: 'Guido'

In [65]: book2 = Book(name='Python', author='Guido')
In [66]: book2.name
Out[66]: 'Python'
```

When test with mixture of positional and keywords arguments,error reports.

```
In [67]: book3 = Book('Python', author='Guido')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The bug can be fixed with multiple conditions or a standard definition `class` without taking `*args` or 'kwargs'.

How to fix it in an elegant method?

Comment: Is it a hard requirement that you use `*args` and `**kwargs`? Because the way you are trying to use them does not match the way in which they were intended/designed.

Comment: So what's the initial intent of them? any material introduced?

Comment: You're trying to unpack: `self.name, self.author = ('Python',)`. Make sure that the input is what you're expecting... check `len(args)` first.

Comment: If you cannot control the number of arguments, passing in a dict can be a solution.

Comment: @DFK  One use for `*args` is for situations where you need to accept an arbitrary number of arguments that you would then process anonymously (possibly in a `for` loop or something like that). `**kwargs` could be for when you need to accept arbitrary named parameters, or if the parameter list is too long for a standard signature. Or you might use the combination of both if you wrote a function wrapper and just want to pass the arguments given to your function to the wrapped function without recreating the signature.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against `*args` and `**kwargs` here, since the way you wish to use them is not they way they were intended to be used. Just use named arguments and you will be able to do all that you want.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, name, author):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
```

Works as expected.

```
In [2]: book1 = Book('Python', 'Guido')

In [3]: book2 = Book(name='Python', author='Guido')

In [4]: book3 = Book('Python', author='Guido')

In [7]: book1.name == book2.name
Out[7]: True

In [8]: book1.name == book3.name
Out[8]: True

In [9]: book2.name == book3.name
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: ty for the patience.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to accept optional `name` and `author` arguments, you should use default arguments:

```
class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, name=None, author=None):
        self.name = name
        self.author = author
```

Not only does this make the class definition simpler, it also conveys better intent in the `__init__` signature:

```
>>> c = Book("best book", "me")
>>> c.name
'best book'
>>> c.author
'me'
>>> c = Book(author="me", name="best book")
>>> c.name
'best book'
>>> c.author
'me'
>>> c = Book("best_book", author="me")
>>> c.name
'best book'
>>> c.author
'me'
```

Comment: Set optional arguments is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against just args and kwargs. But just in case you absolutely need it, here's one way:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       attributes = ['name', 'author']
       for item in zip(attributes, args):
           kwargs[item[0]] = item[1]
       self.name = kwargs.get('name')
       self.author = kwargs.get('author')

    def show(self):
        print('Name={name}, author={author}'.format(name=self.name, author=self.author))

book1 = Book('Python', 'Guido')
book1.show()
book2 = Book(name='Python', author='Guido')
book2.show()
book3 = Book('Python', author='Guido')
```

Execution output:

```
Name=Python, author=Guido
Name=Python, author=Guido
Name=Python, author=Guido
```