# What is meant by the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using PyTorch to do image classification. After training the most, I want to save the trained model.

I don't understand what is meant by

```
the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
```

This line of code is given by PyTorch website (https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/serialization.html).

Comment: This is a generic way to create a new instance of the class `TheModelClass` with some positional arguments (`args`) and named arguments (`kwargs`). It is not particular to pytorch but to python. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding kwargs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: You could read this https://ke-zhang-rd.github.io/krystal/starred.html

Answer (score 0):

This question is that `the_model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)`
means you must define a ModelClass object first. Then you can use the model object to load the disk sequential object. for example:

```
in_feats = data.x.shape[1]
n_hidden = params["n_hidden"]
n_classes = 2
best_model = OwnGCN(in_c=in_feats, hid_c=n_hidden, out_c=n_classes)
best_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```