# Insert values after a pd.DataFrame.query() and keep the original data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1],[3,4],[3,4]], columns=["a", 'b'])
    a   b
0   1   1
1   3   4
2   3   4
```

I have to filter this df based on a query. The query can be complex, but here I'm using a simple one:

```
items = [3,4]
df.query("a in @items and b == 4")
    a   b
1   3   4
2   3   4
```

Only to these rows I would like to add some values in new columns:

```
configuration = {'c': 'action', "d": "non-action"}
for k, v in configuration.items():
    df[k] = v
```

The rest of the rows should have an empty value or np.nan. So my end df should look like:

```
    a   b   c       d
0   1   1   np.nan  np.nan
1   3   4   action  non-action
2   3   4   action  non-action
```

The issue is that to do the query I end up with a copy of a dataframe. And then I have to somehow merged them and replace the modified rows by index. How to do it without replacing in the original df the rows by index with the queried one?

Comment: What don't you do  import numpy as np  and then  `configuration = {'c': np.nan, 'action', 'action', "d":  np.nan , "non-action", "non-action"}}`, sorry if i  don't get correctly.

Comment: @pygo sorry, maybe I wasn't explicit enough. I may have thousands of rows and in configuration just 2 columns with their values configuration = {'c': 'action', "d": "non-action"}. So I have to add those values to a filtered df of thousands of rows, and the other leave them blank or np.nan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `combine_first` with `assign`

```
df.query("a in @items and b == 4").assign(**configuration).combine_first(df)
Out[138]: 
     a    b       c           d
0  1.0  1.0     NaN         NaN
1  3.0  4.0  action  non-action
2  3.0  4.0  action  non-action
```

Comment: nice, didn't know about assign(**configuration)

Comment: @ W-B , you nailed it :-) +1 ,  what does that `assign(**configuration)` here , would be great if you could explain that in the answer section.

Comment: @pygo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean also ,in pandas assign official document https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga, +1 for the POST as well to get new things to Know :-)

Comment: @W-B, thnx for providing the link.