# Convert keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, args, keyword-argument

I have a problem with the dictionary

I don't know how to convert keys to values

I tried to find way to solve this problem on the internet but I didn't understand

```
Expect: "I": 1 => 1:"I"

    convert = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000,}
    new_dict ={}
    for k,v in convert.items():
        new_dict.update({v,k})
```

Comment: You *say* "args to kwargs", but what you're actually showing is swapping keys and values.

Comment: oh sorry so what "args to kwargs" mean? Can you explain it for me?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287085/what-do-args-and-kwargs-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**args** and **kwargs** are totally different things and related to something else **not** values and keys of dictionary..

Now, for what you're asking, you can check this code to achieve what you were asking,

**Code Syntax**

```
convy = {value: key for key, value in convert.items()}
```

**Output**

```
{1: 'I', 5: 'V', 10: 'X', 50: 'L', 100: 'C', 500: 'D', 1000: 'M', 4: 'IV', 9: 'IX', 40: 'XL', 90: 'XC', 400: 'CD', 900: 'CM'}

[Program finished]
```