# Better way to log method calls in Python?

Tags: python, logging

We can code out some sort of logging decorator to echo function/method calls like the following:

```
def log(fn):
    ...

@log
def foo():
    ...

class Foo(object):
    @log
    def foo(self):
        ...

    @log
    def bar(self, a, b):
        ...

    @log
    def foobar(self, x, y, z):
        ...
```

But what if we are like to log method calls without putting that many @log in front of each meth definition? Is there some way to just put one decorator above a class definition to make all its method calls decorated/logged? Or are there some other better and interesting ways to do that instead of decorator?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to explicitly log things? I understand that logging function calls can be helpful to get a better idea what happens when, but in general, at least I would prefer to do some logging in between when it seems appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Attaching a decorator to all functions within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467526/attaching-a-decorator-to-all-functions-within-a-class)

However, as the accepted answer to that question points out, it generally isn't a good idea.

If you decide to go the aspect oriented programming route, I suggest starting here: [Any AOP support library for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286958/any-aop-support-library-for-python)

Comment: Note that the "after the fact" decoration of the methods from the answer to the first linked question can easily be moved into a class decorator instead of doing it inline after the class definition.

Answer (score 32):

This might be overkill, but there is a trace function facility that will inform you of a great deal of activity within your program:

```
import sys

def trace(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "call":
        filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
        if filename == "path/to/myfile.py":
            lineno = frame.f_lineno
            # Here I'm printing the file and line number, 
            # but you can examine the frame, locals, etc too.
            print("%s @ %s" % (filename, lineno))
    return trace

sys.settrace(trace)
call_my_function()
sys.settrace(None)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Use frame.f_code.co_name to get the method name. Documentation for this is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect

Answer (score 15):

It can be done many different ways. I will show how to make it through ***meta-class***, ***class decorator*** and ***inheritance***.

by **changing meta class**

```
import functools


class Logger(type):
    @staticmethod
    def _decorator(fun):
        @functools.wraps(fun)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(fun.__name__, args, kwargs)
            return fun(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        for key in attrs.keys():
            if callable(attrs[key]):
                # if attrs[key] is callable, then we can easily wrap it with decorator
                # and substitute in the future attrs
                # only for extra clarity (though it is wider type than function)
                fun = attrs[key]
                attrs[key] = Logger._decorator(fun)
        # and then invoke __new__ in type metaclass
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class A(metaclass=Logger):
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_val = "some_val"

    def method_first(self, a, b):
        print(a, self.some_val)

    def another_method(self, c):
        print(c)

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(d):
        print(d)


b = A()
# __init__ (<__main__.A object at 0x7f852a52a2b0>,) {}

b.method_first(5, b="Here should be 5")
# method_first (<__main__.A object at 0x7f852a52a2b0>, 5) {'b': 'Here should be 5'}
# 5 some_val
b.method_first(6, b="Here should be 6")
# method_first (<__main__.A object at 0x7f852a52a2b0>, 6) {'b': 'Here should be 6'}
# 6 some_val
b.another_method(7)
# another_method (<__main__.A object at 0x7f852a52a2b0>, 7) {}
# 7
b.static_method(7)
# 7
```

Also, I will show two approaches how to make it without changing meta information of class (through **class decorator** and **class inheritance**). The first approach through **class decorator** `put_decorator_on_all_methods` accepts decorator to wrap all member callable objects of class.

```
def logger(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f.__name__, args, kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def put_decorator_on_all_methods(decorator, cls=None):
    if cls is None:
        return lambda cls: put_decorator_on_all_methods(decorator, cls)

    class Decoratable(cls):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kargs)

        def __getattribute__(self, item):
            value = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
            if callable(value):
                return decorator(value)
            return value

    return Decoratable


@put_decorator_on_all_methods(logger)
class A:
    def method(self, a, b):
        print(a)

    def another_method(self, c):
        print(c)

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(d):
        print(d)


b = A()
b.method(5, b="Here should be 5")
# >>> method (5,) {'b': 'Here should be 5'}
# >>> 5
b.method(6, b="Here should be 6")
# >>> method (6,) {'b': 'Here should be 6'}
# >>> 6
b.another_method(7)
# >>> another_method (7,) {}
# >>> 7
b.static_method(8)
# >>> static_method (8,) {}
# >>> 8
```

And, recently, I've come across on the same problem, but I couldn't put decorator on class or change it in any other way, except I was allowed to add such behavior **through inheritance** only (I am not sure that this is the best choice if you can change codebase as you wish though).

Here class `Logger` forces all callable members of subclasses to write information about their invocations, see code below.

```
class Logger:

    def _decorator(self, f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(f.__name__, args, kwargs)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if callable(value):
            decorator = object.__getattribute__(self, '_decorator')
            return decorator(value)
        return value


class A(Logger):
    def method(self, a, b):
        print(a)

    def another_method(self, c):
        print(c)

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(d):
        print(d)

b = A()
b.method(5, b="Here should be 5")
# >>> method (5,) {'b': 'Here should be 5'}
# >>> 5
b.method(6, b="Here should be 6")
# >>> method (6,) {'b': 'Here should be 6'}
# >>> 6
b.another_method(7)
# >>> another_method (7,) {}
# >>> 7
b.static_method(7)
# >>> static_method (7,) {}
# >>> 7
```

Or more abstractly, you can instantiate base class based on some decorator.

```
def decorator(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f.__name__, args, kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Decoratable:
    def __init__(self, dec):
        self._decorator = dec

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        if callable(value):
            decorator = object.__getattribute__(self, '_decorator')
            return decorator(value)
        return value


class A(Decoratable):
    def __init__(self, dec):
        super().__init__(dec)

    def method(self, a, b):
        print(a)

    def another_method(self, c):
        print(c)

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(d):
        print(d)

b = A(decorator)
b.method(5, b="Here should be 5")
# >>> method (5,) {'b': 'Here should be 5'}
# >>> 5
b.method(6, b="Here should be 6")
# >>> method (6,) {'b': 'Here should be 6'}
# >>> 6
b.another_method(7)
# >>> another_method (7,) {}
# >>> 7
b.static_method(7)
# >>> static_method (7,) {}
# >>> 7
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure what your use case is for this, but generally, I would think more about what exactly is the problem that you're trying to solve.

That said, here's an example that might do what you want but without a decorator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import inspect


class Foo(object):

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self, a, b):
        pass

    def foobar(self, x, y, z):
        pass

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        returned = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if inspect.isfunction(returned) or inspect.ismethod(returned):
            print 'called ', returned.__name__
        return returned


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Foo()
    a.foo()
    a.bar(1, 2)
    a.foobar(1, 2, 3)
```

Output:

```
called  foo
called  bar
called  foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you do not want to explicitly decorate all your functions, you can get all the functions/methods of a given module and apply your decorator automatically. not the easiest thing but not infeasible in python :)

You can also try an aspect oriented programming framework.

my2c

Comment: for name, module in sys.modules.items(): \ for fname,obj in module.__dict__.items(): \  if hasattr(obj, '__call__'): \ sys.modules['name'].__dict__[fname] = log(obj)