# Built-in decorator to log method calls

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-logging

The following code (or custom solutions from [Better way to log method calls in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103735/better-way-to-log-method-calls-in-python) or solutions with `inspect`) works to log method calls:

```
import logging, sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def log(func):
    def logged(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.info(f"{func.__name__} starting with {args=} {kwargs=}...")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.info(f"{func.__name__} finished.")
        return result
    return logged

class A:
    @log
    def foo(self, x, y):
        pass

    @log
    def bar(self, x, y):
        1/0

a = A()
a.foo(2, y=3)
a.bar(2, y=3)
```

Output:

```
INFO:root:foo starting with args=(<__main__.A object at 0x0000000002784EE0>, 2) kwargs={'y': 3}...
INFO:root:foo finished.
INFO:root:bar starting with args=(<__main__.A object at 0x0000000002784EE0>, 2) kwargs={'y': 3}...
...
```

Is there a built-in solution in current Python versions (either in `logging` or in another module)?

Comment: Note to close voter: I'm not "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries", I'm specifically looking for the built-in Python standard method.

Comment: I think you should clarify what a "solution" means for you. What is that you do not like about the code you posted. Do you want to same functionality but you do not want to write a `log` method?

Comment: I think it's very clear that OP wants some built in `@log` or probably some kind of `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG, **log_function_calls=True**)` so you don't have to copy paste `def log(func):` in all your projects.

Comment: Yes exactly @Daviid. Of course, I can create a module for this, and import it in every project, but I was curious if nowadays' Python has something like this built-in in `logging` or elsewhere.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial  There is a config file for steamhandler not sure if that helps... from there... Note It is strongly advised that you do not log to the root logger in your library. Instead, use a logger with a unique and easily identifiable name, such as the __name__ for your library’s top-level package or module. Logging to the root logger will make it difficult or impossible for the application developer to configure the logging verbosity or handlers of your library as they wish.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not any utility like this provided in the standard libraries. Logging format, usage of root logger vs module specific one, log level chosen, values logged, etc, are all going to be application specific. The arguments would have to be super complex/detailed if this were to make it into a flexible builtin lib.

Comment: Not related to this question. But it kind of sounds like you should investigate traces. https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/traces/

Comment: I don't get what motivates you to find an equivalent function from the standard library in the first place. Even if a function from the standard library did exactly what you want you would still need to write an `import` statement for it where you want it. It is in no way different from importing a function from your own module. And no there is nothing in the standard library that does exactly what your `log` decorator function does AFAIK, so you'd be perfectly fine to continue using the decorator you have. If you want it implicitly applied to all your functions then it's a different question.

Comment: @blhsing: my reasoning is the following: very often I've coded custom solutions for some features, and realized a few years later that in recent Python versions (or e.g. Numpy depending on the context), such functions already existed built-in ;) That's why I'm asking here if something close to this exists in modern Python versions, directly in `logging`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There is no @log-like decorator in Python 3.12.1's logging module

I looked through the source code and test code for logging and didn't see any functionality that allowed any type of declarative way of identifying methods to log nor did I find any tests that tested any type of decorator in the logging module tests.