# centralized logging method and logging current line number

Tags: python, logging

I have a class inherited by many other classes. Related class have a logging method and logs some extra parameters beside the text I wish to log:

```
import logging
# some lines to set logger 
log = logging.getLogger('some_loger')

class SomeClass:
    def log_it(self, log_text):
        log.info(self.some_param + self.some_other_param + log_text + self.some_another_param)
```

And in any file that inherits `SomeClass`:

```
class MyOtherClass(SomeClass):
    def some_method(self):
        ...
        ...
        self.log_it('let me log this text')
```

I also wish to log the current line number (line that calls `self.log_it`) so I can easily find the current logging line in the related file.

What is the best pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Side-note and not a direct answer to your question, you may be interested in [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) if you're not familiar with the concept. This style of programming is usually best exemplified with logging use cases. Also see this post if you want to read more + Python support http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356713/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-python . A proof of concept: https://bitbucket.org/jsbueno/metapython/src/f48d6bd388fd/aspect.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` package to find the calling line of code.

I use this method to mark a function as deprecated and then track down the callers (in your unit tests of course).  You can adjust to your logging needs.

## Tattletale logging

In the file that will log (a.py):

```
import logging # of course you have this
import inspect

# some lines to set logger 
log = logging.getLogger('some_loger')
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

class SomeClass:
    def log_it(self, log_text):
        log.warn("DEPRECATION WARNING: {0[3]} was called from {1[3]} at line {1[2]} in {1[1]}".format(*inspect.stack()[:2]))
```

In the "child" file (b.py):

```
from a import SomeClass

class MyOtherClass(SomeClass):
    def some_method(self):
        self.log_it('let me log this text')~

b = MyOtherClass()
b.some_method()
```

Running b.py:

```
> python b.py
DEPRECATION WARNING: log_it was called from some_method at line 5 in b.py
```

check out [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) for details on what's in the stack.