# In Python, is it possible to accept a function call template as a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

As part of improving the syntax for Aspect-Oriented Programming in Python based on the excellent answer by jsbueno: [Aspect oriented programming (AOP) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356713/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-python) , I was wondering if it's possible to accept a function template as a parameter in Python with any decoration.

Eg, being able to call `foo(bar(5))` with `bar` undefined, and have `foo` receive an object representing the expression `bar(5)`; rather than an error that `bar` is undefined. (This would then be used as an input to construct a rule for matching incoming network messages indicating that another node has run function `bar` with parameter 5.)

Is there any better way to do this than passing the template as a string and parsing it with `ast`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What will function `foo()` do when `bar` is undefined?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for without knowing more context, but couldn't you just accept `bar` as a parameter to the enclosing function, then pass in whatever function you want to be used?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea to me. With a syntax like that, you have to always be aware of which functions actually exist (like `foo`) and which are pseudo-functions (like `bar`). If you later define a `bar` method, suddenly your old code might stop working - or at the very least it'll be ambiguous. It might look convenient now, but when you actually have to use it...

Comment: I wouldn't mind if there was some annotation to apply to the syntax to indicate this (but ideally not just making it a string)

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure, what your looking for, maybe this will help:

```
def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("f in wraper with: {}".format(f.__defaults__))
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

funcs = {}
fdefaults = [1, 2, 3]
code = """def myfunc(x={}): return print("f returning:", *x)""".format(fdefaults)

exec(code, {}, funcs)
myfunc = decorator(funcs["myfunc"])
myfunc()
```

outputs:
f in wraper with: ([1, 2, 3],)
f returning: 1 2 3