# Logging without altering code in Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I work a lot in both Ruby and Python. I am quite comfortable with the usual debuggers, but I still find myself still entering **puts** or **print** statements in the code. 
**Why?** Because I want to inspect variables without having to stop and start the code. This is especially important for long sequences of code such as background processing.

The problem of course is the code is then littered with these statements. Sometimes I need to add a note, or unpack an array so some additional logic. Later after the code goes to production and a new problem is found I might need to put the print / puts back in. It would be good to be able to store them externally to the actual program code.

Are there any tools that allow the creation of variable logging at specific points in the code, as well as the ability to run short snippets of code for print presentation?

Comment: Sounds to me like Ruby lacks a pre-processor. Have you thought about using a preprocessor like m4? :)

Comment: There are numerous logging libraries for both languages. What's your problem with using one of them?

Comment: @delnan The problem is that any logging litters the code. I was wondering if there was a way to keep logging completely out of the code, in the way that a IDE can remember breakpoints.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko Isn't m4 used as part of the compile phase in compiled languages?

Comment: @unutbu I like that idea. A lot. Can you expand and add it as answer?

Comment: @ardochhigh: m4 is just a pre-processor, it can be used for many things. In languages like C or C++, a different pre-processor is used. But the idea is that you can run ruby code through m4 to get rid of loging or put it back easily.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko That sounds interesting. Are there any examples of such use out on the internet that you know of?

Comment: @ardochhigh: I am a low-level guy, so I can't say about Ruby, but here is an example using it with assembler - http://silversoft.net/src/ircbot2.s I'd say that it is easier to use m4 that git branching&merging as in unutbu's answer, IMHO.

Comment: Logging code is not litter. When done well, logging is golden, especially when logs are kept for a long time which allows me to compare successes and failures over time.  You are approaching your problem with prejudices against logging.  The use-case you describe is what logging is exactly designed for.

Comment: I think it is not a prejudice against logging. The OP want to have logging. Instead he sees logging as what it is: a different concern which has nothing to do with the business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often there are different concerns (= different aspects of the program) like business logic, persistence, or **logging** entangled in the same code.
[Aspect-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming)[oriented](http://www.aspectprogramming.com/home/aosd)-[programming](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/AOP_in_Ruby.pdf) (AOP) solves that problem by separating those concerns into different modules.
One AOP framework for ruby is [aquarium](http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/), there are [AOP libraries for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286958/any-aop-support-library-for-python) too, but the most famous AOP library is [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) (for Java).

Logging of variables without altering the actual source code is *the* famous example of AOP.
The first example on the [aquarium page](http://aquarium.rubyforge.org/) handles your use case. The example logs every method call (and their arguments) of classes which end with `Service` without altering the `-Service` classes themselves:

```
class ServiceTracer
  include Aquarium::DSL
  # jp => the current "join point"
  before :calls_to => :all_methods, :in_types => /Service$/ do |jp, object, *args|
    names = "#{jp.target_type.name}##{jp.method_name}"
    log "Entering: #{names}: object = #{object}, args = #{args}" 
  end
end
```

Of course more advances method selections (than 'give me every method call of every class ending with `Service`') are possible.

Answer (score 3):

Using a version control system like `git`, you could make a `logging` branch off of the `master` branch which includes the logging statements.

That way, you'd have a clean (master) version, and a logging version.

As commits are added to `master`, you could update your logging branch using `rebase`:

```
git checkout logging
git rebase --interactive master
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:
Maybe you could write a logging decorator that would satisfy some of your requirements. You can find examples of logging decorators for python by googling "logging decorator python".