# Monkey patching with subclass

Tags: python, cherrypy, monkeypatching

*Context:[cherrypy session](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/refman/lib/sessions.html) currently locks on request start and releases the lock when the request ends. Hence concurrent requests are processed serially and getting blocked.*

Is it possible to extend a class, overwrite a few methods where the new methods call the parent method and then monkey patch the result?

Example:

```
from cherrypy.lib import sessions
class LockingSession(sessions.RamSession):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # acquire lock
        super(LockingSession).get(*args, **kwargs)
        # release lock
sessions.RamSession = LockingSession
```

*The example doesn't work - infinite loop :-)*

Would this be the correct approach. Is this possible at all? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm not sure about monkey patching, but I'd try inject your class into the `sessions` module instead of replacing existing one and then enable it in config. Look at this line https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py#L784
They pick class declared in module by name in config. You should probably use this.

Comment: Here's an example of custom session class with redis backend:
https://bitbucket.org/webknjaz/blueberrypy-wk/src/cb2753de29c4ec0f1be00baf2e828b35e0939b47/src/blueberrypy/command.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#command.py-269:270
https://bitbucket.org/webknjaz/blueberrypy-wk/src/cb2753de29c4ec0f1be00baf2e828b35e0939b47/src/blueberrypy/session.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#session.py-33:91

Comment: Didn't know about Mokey patching :) I know it as Aspect Oriented Programming. Maybe this thread can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286958/any-aop-support-library-for-python

Comment: With `super()` or `super(LockingSession, self)` I'm getting: `>>> sessions.RamSession = LockingSession`
`>>> t = sessions.RamSession()`
`>>> t.get("A")`
`[28/Jun/2016:10:33:54] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Session cleanup'.`
What error are you getting? You shouldn't be getting an infinite loop, since `self(LockingSession, [])` references an object pointer, not a name.

Comment: Wow. Missed that typo... `super(LockingSession, [...])` references a class descriptor reference (which is an object of type `super` in this case, but uses a reference to the original `type` object), not a name.

Comment: Hello @kev, I just want to inform you, that there's a new way of specifying session class available: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull/1495

Comment: @kev did my answer help you?

Comment: I know this is late, but I'm curious why not just patch the get function?

Comment: So many comments, and still no answer to a smile question. lol

Answer (score 0):

## UPD (Oct 1, 2016):

This [pull request](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull/1495) (merged on Sep 4, 2016 and available for `CherryPy >= 8.1`) introduces a new way of specifying session class.
Smth like this should serve your needs:

```
import cherrypy

class Root:
    ...

class LockingSession(sessions.RamSession):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # acquire lock
        super(LockingSession).get(*args, **kwargs)
        # release lock

conf = {
    ...,
    'tools.sessions.storage_class': LockingSession,
    ...,
}

cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/', conf)
```

## Old answer:

Following should work:

```
from cherrypy.lib import sessions
class LockingSession(sessions.RamSession):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # acquire lock
        super(LockingSession).get(*args, **kwargs)
        # release lock

sessions.LockingSession = LockingSession
```

Comment: Not true in python 2.7.6 or 3.4.3. This is due to the fact that once an object is specified in the definition of a class, the object reference is used, not the name, and you cannot overwrite that object's reference with '='. Where did you test your claims?

Comment: Not I didn't, I just compared working and non-working code snippets and made these suggestions.

Comment: @Poik it seems you are right. Perhaps topic starter experiences different issue

Comment: Asked for clarification, but perhaps I am a little verbose. Also, I appear to need more coffee.