# What are the possible AOP use cases?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, aop, use-case

I'd like to make a picture of what are the possible cases for effective involvement of AOP in application design. All I have met so far is:

- logging-related
- security checks
- transaction management
- tweaking of a legacy application

Anything else?

(It doesn't have to be necessarily Spring's proxy based AOP - rather JBoss AOP.)

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155936/how-to-introduce-aop-into-productive-software-development))

Comment: "the possible cases"?  That's a nearly *infinite* collection.  Not all are a good idea, however.  Put all are possible.  Is there any way to narrow or focus that question?

Comment: Read well: the question contained "the possible cases for effective invovement of AOP in application design". By that I mean cases where it's a good idea to use AOP. Sorry if the question is not clear.

Comment: Should be community wiki

Comment: "Effective Involvement" seems like an invitation to simply list every possible way AOP can be used.  "Effective" is a slippery term, and without some kind of qualification or filtering, the dumbest AOP technique could be called "effective" by an AOP fan.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I can give you two examples where we use it:

- Automatically registering objects in JMX for remote management.  If a class is annotated with our `@AutoRegister` annotation, we have an aspect that watches for new instantiations of that class and registers them in JMX automatically.
- Audit logging (the gold standard AOP use case).  Its a bit coarse but the general approach is to annotate methods that represent some auditable action.  Combined with something like Spring Security, we can get a pretty good idea of:

  - who the user is
  - what method they're invoking
  - what data they're providing
  - what time the method was invoked
  - whether the invocation was successful or not (i.e., if an exception was thrown)

Comment: can aop be used for business code ? assume I have a presenter that you can set a view to it or NOT (mvp). then I dont wanna keep checking if view is null for every call to view can I handle this null check before any call to view methods ?

Comment: @Kevin: How do you handle audit failure in this case? Do you mark audit failed if it throws any exception, even trivial exceptions like dividebyzero,nullpointer-exception?

Answer (score 15):

- Exception Handling: don't need to repeat the horrible list of try ... catch, catch, catch etc - also means the exception handling is guaranteed to be consistent.
- Performance monitoring: Very useful as using an aspect is non intrusive and can be done after the fact and then turned off when no longer required.

Wow... 10 years ago - didn't have much for AOP... Here are a few more

- Be able to customise objects where you don't have access to their constructor (e.g. jpa entities)
- Implementing security rules (security says user is not allowed to call this method - AOP can implement that)
- Transaction manager (begin, commit, rollback)
- Caching - want to cache the result of a method and not call it again

Answer (score 7):

To see the coverage of AOP in terms of applicability I really recommend you to read the book [Aspect-Oriented-Software-Development-Use-Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268881). This book elaborates use cases of functional and non-functional requirements using AOP. After that you will see that aspects can be used to more requirements than logging, tracing, security, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Method level caching,if your method is stateless(I mean returns same value when invoked repeatedly with same parameter values). This is more effective in case of DAO methods because it avoids database hit.

Answer (score 5):

- **Read/write locks**. Instead of replicating the same snippet, I used an aspect to define the methods that needed a read lock or an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 5):

We use it for software license management, i.e. allow the software to run only if the computer has some specific license(s) installed. It is not that different from your listed uses, since it is a form of security check.

I published a blog entry describing a practical implementation [here](http://technomilk.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/combining-annotations-and-aspects-part-1/)

Answer (score 4):

One effective use of AOP, besides all those you listed, can be validation. Validation of user input, or business objects.

Related articles you must look at.

- [AOP@Work: Design with pointcuts to avoid pattern density](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-aopwork7/index.html)
- [AOP@Work: Enhance design patterns with AspectJ, Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-aopwork6/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I will also recommend aspects for:

- Async method calls
- Monitoring

With Spring and tcServer (developer), you can easily monitor all your Spring beans with 
@Component annotation. You can see time used, the input and return data including exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

INotifyPropertyChanged and similar horrors.

Basically wherever there is code that looks like this - use an aspect and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime checking of code contracts. [Code Contracts for .NET](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) use AOP for

> Runtime Checking. Our binary rewriter modifies a program by injecting the contracts, which are checked as part of program execution.

Answer (score 1):

We use AspectJ to accomplish AOP. Use cases apart from the above mentioned ones are as follows:

- Restricting access to method calls to only few classes.
- Automatically annotating selected methods/classes/fields.

Comment: How do you automatically annotate methods? We need to apply annotations at compile time right?