# Aspectj concept in eclipse

Tags: java, aspectj

Hi I am new to aspectj and after several hours of browsing around the internet I came to know something about aspectj. And also I had one doubt is this similar to immediate window in visual studio as in the aspectj in which we doing manually checking joint points...In immediate window if we type any variable it returns its value in current method. Likewise, in aspectj we are declaring manually that after calling specified function and returing variable values inside that method using  system.out.println(). Is that right? if it is wrong...correct me

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question, but if I understand correctly you are likening pointcuts to setting breakpoints and inspecting variables?

Comment: The behaviour does seem very similar, but debugging is not done using aspects. How familiar are you with AOP? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Comment: I am learning it for some days...But I have one doubt why we go for AOP and can I debug a program using it

Comment: Debugging AOP is like debugging anything else in Java, breakpoints will still fire and you can even write units tests for it. AOP has very specific use cases though. Maybe you can change you question to include you use case

Comment: From ur point,what I understand is " AOP is manual way of using break points"..correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Can u tell me the specific use cases of AOP...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62592/discussion-between-leon-and-user3797438).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wikipeida article: AOP is a programming paradigm that aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns

Think about caching.... that is a concern that cuts across other concerns, like reading from a datastore. You can create a point cut to cache values being written to datastore and one to read from cache when the datastore is being accessed. Here is a link to a question specifically about AOP use cases: [AOP use cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197051/aop-use-cases)

If you want to use AOP to "watch" a variable, to short answer is you can't. Pointcuts can only be applied methods